# Are all badges supposed to be attainable for all users?

Tags: discussion, badges

I've looked over the badges and I like the idea of positive badges.  However, is the purpose behind the badges to make it for everyone to get a badge if they want to?

It's implied that way in the FAQ, but there are a few badges I can't get because of some personal convictions on the use of my time.  I'll leave it at that for an explanation.

It's not an issue with me as there are lots of other badges available, but I was curious about it.

Comment: Related: [Why are beta badges being awarded at all?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/why-are-beta-badges-awarded-at-all)

Comment: I'm not a likely candidate for a generalist badge either. My profile should lend a clue as to part of the reason why :) Keep in mind, that badge (and I think it's the one you're most considering) had no criteria for being awarded for a very long time. Still, it's a nice way to say 'thanks' to people that know quite a bit about a lot of different technologies for contributing, and that's something we should be doing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not all badges are attainable. Perhaps the greatest examples of this would be the Beta and Precognitive badges, the former of which was time sensitive, while the latter of which is completely impossible to obtain on Stack Overflow/Server Fault/Super User/Meta (and is likewise time sensitive on other sites).

Go for badges that are within your comfort zone - focus on the *goals* of those badges, not the numerics. For obvious reasons, one shouldn't *strive* to post content that gets downvoted enough for Peer Pressure, for example - it is meant to encourage your action if you end up there on your own device. For Unsung Hero, just acknowledge the importance of helping *anyone*, no matter whether you get recognition, even in small topics. For edit badges, even if you can't afford the time to reach it with haste, just keep in the back of your mind how helpful it is to lend a hand with editing. And naturally, if you can't afford to stick around for 100 days, don't sweat it - the badge is for people who make it that far and have the time for that.

Comment: Excellent answer!  You got to the heart of the question and yes that was one of the badges that I hinted at. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All* badges are theoretically attainable.

Whether you can actually achieve them is another matter. You might not have participated since the [beta](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/30/beta), you might not want to [fill out your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/9/autobiographer) or you might not want to [share links](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer).

<sup>* Except for the [Precognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive) badge on the original Trilogy sites and here</sup>