# Show the progress left on badge achievement unlockings

Tags: feature-request, badge-progress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO Badge Progress Report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report)

I love achievements and I wish there were more of them.

For some of the achievements it's difficult to see how close I am to obtaining them.

I wish there was a progress meter, especially for badges such as **[Generalist]** and **[Copy Editor]**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good idea.

I can understand that some should be difficult to obtain, but it's nice to see your progress on more common ones.

Answer (score 1):

The obscurity is `by-design`; but you can track your progress with the Data Explorer:

http://odata.stackexchange.com