# Progress percentage for Badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow users to see badge progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69441/allow-users-to-see-badge-progress)
>   [Show the progress left on badge achievement unlockings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63941/show-the-progress-left-on-badge-achievement-unlockings)
>
> Both of the above questions are now closed as exact duplicates of [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report)

I think for the more long term Badges there should be some kind of progress bar beside it to show how close/far away you are from receiving it.

Much like this:

http://hwbot.org/community/user/mutant_tractor?tab=achievements

Image here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxEEz.png]

Comment: This has been proposed numerous times: [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69441/allow-users-to-see-badge-progress), [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63941/show-the-progress-left-on-badge-achievement-unlockings), [tag badge-specific](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62242/tag-badge-progress), [editor badge-specific](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/how-do-i-estimate-strunk-white-progress). See also [a related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report) that people close as dupe of. There're more but I'm out of chars

Comment: @Pop: question links can be shortened as http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69441, this allows you to add 4 or maybe 5 more links.

Comment: @BalusC nice!!!

Comment: @BalusC, yeah, true story. I didn't feel like it was worth the effort, but I appreciate the assist.

Comment: I think this should be raised again, I read the above threads and the reason give was it is modelled on the xbox live achievements scheme which is like that by design, many more "addictive" games now-adays DO show progress and encourages more use by the user as they can see "Oh im only XX away from XXXX badge". Thats just my thoughts though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important point though, you probably don't want a progress badge for every question though, because every question/answer has the potential of gaining enough votes to award a medal.

Could instead just put "X Votes away from $medal" with a list of the top contenders for each medal.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that we implement a medal system, rather just show progress in each Badge (the larger ones anyway)

Comment: @Myles ~ Define `larger`. <-- Welcome to programming.

Comment: Larger - as in ones that require more than one event/occurrence to achieve.

Comment: Larger means all but the lowest ranked one right? Where  is the (arbitrary) boundary fence?