# Allow users to see badge progress

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO Badge Progress Report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report)

I would like for users to be able to track their progress towards certain badges. For example, they should be able to see the number of edits they must still perform to earn the Copy Editor badge. For different kind of badges like Nice Question, the tracker should show the most upvoted question by that user.