# How can I know how many [something] I still need to get a particular badge?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports)

Is there a way to know how many edits/views/votes/&c. I still need to earn a particular badge?

For example, to get a **Copy Editor** badge, a user needs to edit 500 posts. How can I know how many edits I have made so far?

I want to keep of track of my progress (i.e. how close I am) towards receiving other badges in the same way.

Comment: What to do when both answers are correct and have solved my question equally? I dont know which one to accept.

Comment: accept either or neither, it's up to you. There are various options: 1. You could accept one and then assign a bounty to the other. 2. You could accept one but only upvote the other.

Comment: Okay, trying this close again. It may not be an _exact_ duplicate, but almost all badge progress questions here are closed as duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't see your current progress for most badges.  The only way would be to see if you could write a query on http://odata.stackexchange.com/

<strike>There may even be a query already there.</strike>

I have just created a query [here](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/669/edits-by-user) - which is based on [this query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/303/top-50-most-prolific-editors)

Comment: Wow, thanks for that, but I am looking to check status of all the badges

Comment: @Starx - you can't check your status of all badges.  It is based on the Xbox Live achievements model.  [See this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report)

Answer (score 5):

To answer your specific question this query:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges

will give you a rough idea of your progress towards the various editor badges. It's not 100% accurate as you need to be the last editor of a post for it to count as your edit. So if someone comes along and edits the same post afterwards your edit count will be reduced.

*Thanks to Andy E's Head for pointing that out*.

Comment: isn't there a way to track all badge status

Comment: @Starx - you'd need a different query for each badge. Originally the intention was for badges to come as a surprise which is why there's no direct option on the UI.

Comment: That query may be rather inaccurate since it only checks posts where you were the last editor.  Any edits made after your own will change that field.  Still good enough for a rough idea of how close you are, though - +1

Comment: @Andy - good point - I'll update the answer.