# Show how many more actions are left to earn particular badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports)

Wouldn't it be nice to know how many more activities are required to earn a particular badge? This information could be displayed somewhere in users' profiles.

Ee.g. Copy Editor requires editing 600 entries, so I would like to know that I have edited, say, 527 entries and need 73 more for the badge. Pundit requires ten comments with score of five or more, and I'd like to be able to either hover over the badge or see in my profile how many comments I have left that have score of at least five.

This could be done for several badges.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to search for one. May be I didnt search with the right keyword. But I thought it should be there.

Comment: I know that feeling-- the "Related" sidebar is consistently much better at searching than I am :)

Comment: There are several badges where you can track your progress (Strunk & White, Copy Editor, Reviewer, Civic Duty, Electorate, Deputy, Marshall, Entusiast, Fanatic, among several others...), but some that you can't. They're intended to be surprises when you earn them, general guidance towards doing good things on the site rather than grinding for rewards.