# See badge progress

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

Is there a way to see progress of some badges?

If there is no way, why not implement it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143653/254746

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Many of the badges have [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) queries you can use to measure your progress. For example, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/35591/generalist-progression-updated) lists your progress towards getting the generalist badge.

Answer (score 14):

I can answer part of your question:

> If there is no way, why not implement?

Answer: because development time costs money.  The team needs to prioritize its work.  If there are higher priority tasks, they will come first.