# Is it possible to know how many competing answers I upvoted?

Tags: feature-request, badges, up-votes, sportsmanship-badge

I am trying to achieve the [Sportsmanship badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship). I wonder if it's possible to know how many times I upvoted competing answers until now?

Comment: On the topic, is it even possible to know any of those statistics. Like, how many have I flagged.

Comment: How many flagged you can see in your profile (flag weight).

Comment: @Bugai13 - not strictly true. It will give you a guide, but if a flag is marked as invalid your flag weight goes down. So flagging 2 valid and 1 invalid will give you the same weight as if you'd flagged 1 valid.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, you true, +1. It's actually 'flag weight' but not just how many times i have flagged. But for 'Deputy' badge need achieve a flag weight of 500.

Comment: Guys its not about flags and flags weight its about upvoting competing answers ...

Comment: @O.D - Bugai13 was responding to Gunner's comment - which was about flags.

Comment: I'll tag the Question with a feature Request tag.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS there shouldn't be a badge for something if the behavior it encourages is bad.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS Just because someone wants to track the progress of this badge it doesn't mean they are voting just to get it.

Comment: Just because someone wants the badge it doesn't mean that they are voting just to get the badge. People do like to track progress of achievements and badges are just achievements.

Comment: Would you consider accepting more relevant answer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I wonder if it's possible to know how many times I upvoted competing answers until now

<s>No, it's not possible.</s> As of April 2015, this is possible using the features of the new profile page, as described in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250175/152859).

Such data is not exposed, neither in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) nor in the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) since voting is anonymous.

Worth to mention in this context that there were already [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80700/152859) [suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3230/152859) regarding badge progress.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80700/see-badge-progress. It's been suggested before.

Comment: Thanks @Bel I didn't see this before. :)

Comment: Also this is not possible through Data.SE since voting is anonymous on Data.SE too.

Comment: @hims056 thanks, I think I wasn't aware of data explorer and API back then, time to update my answer. :)

Comment: Time to update your answer even more, now the profile's show progress ;) (wonder how many wrong answers and pointless questions now exist because of changes...)

Comment: @James no need, nicael already posted a separate answer which is fine. OP can choose to accept his answer any time. :)

Answer (score 13):

Technically speaking you can check such data at [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). (However, the data gets updated weekly, so it won't be 100% accurate.)

**[How close am I to Sportsmanship badge?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/102373/how-close-am-i-to-the-sportsmanship-badge)**
This query returns all your answers, where you upvoted the competitor.

You can see the total values of the returns, at the bottom of the table.

You only need your *userid*. You can acquire your *userid* from the URL of your profile page.

Comment: Does the sportsmanship badge counts only the answers, that are upvoted at least one time?

Comment: Yes, your questions will need a positive score for competing upvoted answers to count. So the first query seems best: I don't have the badge and the first query gives 93 results and the second gives 196.

Comment: This queery is wrong!

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub It worked 4 years ago. Copy the code and make it to your own.

Answer (score 11):

With the [introduction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) of new "activity" tab of profile page, it is now possible (but this new page is only tested on MSE right now):

> [image]

You can now select "Sportsmanship" by clicking on the pencil and choosing the badge.

Comment: I suppose this can now be edited; the page is live!

Comment: This of course only works if you haven't already achieved the badge, but i guess that wasn't the focus of the question.