# View progress of Sportsmanship badge

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to know how many competing answers I did upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84011/is-it-possible-to-know-how-many-competing-answers-i-did-upvote)

I'm sorry if this is not a valid question or has been asked.

Is there a way to view ones progress on the [Sportsmanship badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship) (much like how you can view your Progress on the Copy Editor and Electorate badges)?

Comment: Sort your list of answers by votes. Visit each one that has at least one vote, and count how many competing answers you've upvoted. Add this up across all your answers and you have your progress!