# Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page, feedback

We've launched! Please give feedback [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list).

---

Today, we're shipping the new "Activity Page" of the Profile here on Meta SE, so you can test it out and hopefully share some feedback and suggestions before we ship it network wide.  Hate words?  Assuming you're signed in, just click your face up in the top bar, and you can see it right now. Or, keep reading...

### Quick Background

You may recall that we're breaking the current "profile" page into two views, to address two use cases:

- **[The "Profile Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)" - When you click someone *else's* user card, by default, you'll see a view designed to give a better overall summary of who they are:** Their location, their "About me," what tech/tags they're most active in, their top posts, etc. This page has been live on MSE for a while, and [you've given us a ton of great feedback,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns) most of which is already live.
- **The "Activity Page" - When you click on [your *own* user card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current), you should see a page emphasizing your actual activity** - what you've done, how big an impact you've had helping others, and what you can go do next, if you're so inclined.

Note that both pages will still be visible to everyone (although some fields aren't, for obvious reasons).  So, you can look at other users' "Activity" page, and your own "Profile", that's just not the tab that'll be displayed by default.

### The Old Activity Page

Let's think about when you're *looking at your own page*, and start with what the old page (still live on the rest of the network) was good at.  Here's the bottom of the page:

[image: The Old Activity Page Bottom Half]

It's efficient, and evolved over time, based on what power users told us they needed.

**So, let's change it for change's sake!  New Things are SHINY, and lead to a brighter - if poorly thought out and short lived - future!** Huh. That's actually a pretty awful idea.  So, let's leave the content, and pretty much everything else down there *exactly* how it was, and not mess up anyone's workflow. With the exception of some minor styling tweaks, the actual activity section you interact with today - both the content and the layout - is unchanged.

Now, lets take a look at the top of the page. Remember that the top part doesn't change when you drill down to different activity tabs; it's always there. Again, think of the case where you're *looking at your own profile*:

[image: The Old Activity Page User Details]

So, personally, I'm not that frequently going to my profile to, say... double check what my name is.  Or confirm what city I live in.  Or see if my age has changed. (Actually, the last one may feel like a waste *most* days, but ~0.3% of the time, it reminds me it's my birthday - YAY!)

Now, the point isn't that this was dumb design; it wasn't.  When the page had to serve both use cases, this info made sense, but when you're looking at your own profile, there's no reason to always be showing you a bunch of things that A) you know and can't realistically forget, B) almost never change, and C) only do get changed by you.

So, we've replaced them, with a new section designed to better summarize your overall activity and contributions.  And we've tossed some totally new features in, too.

### The New Activity Page (aka "Top Boxes")

[image: New Activity Page (Redesign of top half)]

The basic goals were:

1. Don't mess up the bottom part that's working, or make the top part any bigger
2. Replace static, known personal data with dynamic, big-picture summaries of users' contributions
3. Do more to help users track their contributions beyond rep and badge counts (more prominent stats on edits, flags, votes, and [the new "People Reached" stat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here).
4. Show users at all levels "what they can do next" and help more new ones learn the ropes gradually
5. Address power-users needs better

I'm not going to walk through all the changes. I'd rather let you go touch it and share your thoughts, but here are a couple of features worth highlighting:

**"Progress to next badge"** bar automatically selects the badge you're closest to earning (or that's most logical to go for next), and tracks your progress toward earning it. It also helps walk new users through a *slightly* more guided intro, nudging them to read the "About" page, etc. For most badges, it not only explains how to earn 'em, but also links to a (mostly) logical place to go try to do so:

[image: Badge Progress Tool tip]

**Progress to next privilege** better conveys an attainable milestone, so users have a target to work toward that's a *little* less daunting than "catch Skeet". And it adapts for our most valuable users, too.  [Once you have earned all the privileges,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9yKJeUesIQ) you should first and foremost take a pause to celebrate how many frigging people you helped.  (The "People Reached" stat is a nice rough estimate).  Have a drink, maybe. But after that, we want you to be able to track goals, too, so the "next privilege" bar automatically switches to tracking your progress toward your closest tag badge. Plus, you can change it if you want to pick a different one (like [this poor soul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) might want to do):

[image: Badge Progress Loading Bar]

### The broader context:

As of now, *both* pages are live here on Meta, so you can try out how they work together. We're rolling out a couple of new features on the "Profile" side as well:

- **Dedicated fields to share your OSS projects or online presence** (Dedicated fields for Github, Twitter, etc.) and new fields in the edit page for them. Note that they're totally optional, and leaving them out won't leave weird blank entries.
- **New "Hide a community" from my profile** feature, (found on the "Edit & Settings" tab.)  This came from community feedback, and helps users who may not want their SO Profile - which their boss might stumble upon - to prominently feature their top questions from, oh, I dunno...[The Workplace, say](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18119/what-is-a-friendly-way-to-let-managers-know-that-having-good-developers-is-a-p).  (It's not a true *privacy setting,* as the connection between accounts *can* be made with some work, like through the API, but it lets you control what sites are or are not featured on your profile page.)

Note: If you can, please post any suggestions or feedback on the changes to the "Edit/Settings" or the "Profile" page (the one others see) as a new post here on MSE. Ideally, we want to keep the answers here  on this post focused on the activity side ("Top Boxes"), since that bit's brand new, and we want to see what suggestions there  are important to the most people.

### We LOVE it.  But, as Joel keeps telling me, no one cares what *I* think.

We want to know what you think.  Go touch it.  Play with it. Tell us what you like (seriously). More importantly, what tweaks or adjustments should we make before we ship it network wide?  Anything missing that you use all the time?

There are some places where we *know* we want to make some changes, but we wanted to wait for feedback to determine what approach makes the most sense.  (For example, we're fairly sure more tooltips are needed, but having them everywhere makes a mess, so we did them for the most obvious places, but waited for your feedback before adding more, to see where they may be needed most.)

As always, thanks in advance for your feedback - it always helps us ship something better than whatever we started with.

Comment: The new badge progress page is awesome! But I fear it might lead to a lot of actions just for the sake of gettng the badge and not to improve the site.

Comment: @juergend, thanks! The goal is always to ensure that badges and other reinforcements *mostly* drive more positive behavior, while accepting that any (even lightly) gamified system will attract some abuse, and be ready to address it in those rare cases ya have to.

Comment: Is the hidden communities also hidden from mods? As a mod on Programmers, I need easy access to their profiles on other sites to check to see if they have cross posted a question before I migrate. If they hide communities, it may be harder to do that.

Comment: I love how Balpha's next tag badge goal is for the [tag:status-declined] badge. Way to encourage him! :-P

Comment: Are you going to show hidden accounts to staff/moderators in a different way? For example greyed out or with a different background.

Comment: What is the max size of the stored profile image?

Comment: @juergend - normal imgur image size limits (2Mb, if memory serves)

Comment: Yay! I will always be 39 now!! Thanks @Jaydles!

Comment: This is *really* minor, but the tooltip for "1,760 votes cast" says it includes accept votes, but I added my up & downvotes together, and it equaled 1,760, so I have a feeling it doesn't include accept votes.

Comment: @hichris123 - you are correct, accept votes are not included. I am amending the tooltip.

Comment: So... how do we see this new page???  *The "Activity Page" - When you click on your own user card, you should see a page emphasizing your actual activity* I've done this (by opening a recent answer and clicking on my name--not sure how else to trigger this) and still see the old page?  What magic incantations should I be using?

Comment: @Won't - you don't see it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1228/wont?tab=activity)?

Comment: This isn't that bad.. From all the old designs I thought it would be terrible, but it's not that bad.. Now can I have the old design back please?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS, we'll accept that as the absolute best compliment we possibly could have received from you. And it's appreciated (for real).

Comment: @Oded bugger all it's on meta only.

Comment: @Won't - yeah, didn't the "here on Meta SE" tip you off? We are collecting feedback, will act on it and ship to the network as soon as we possibly can.

Comment: @Oded did you **see** how many words there are in this question???  Did you **expect** me to read them all?  I just wanted clicky and oooo shiny.  Is that too much to ask?

Comment: @Won't - I'm with you. If only that was mentioned at the start of the wall of text.

Comment: Your freehand-drawings are gorgeous. And the activity page is cool btw!

Comment: @Bigood, I *know*, right?  (Everytime I draw anything in public, Jin, our Creative Director files a "hostile workplace" complaint with HR.)

Comment: Nice job, at least here at work on my great big monitor.  (Will check my tablet at home later.)  Thank you for leaving the bottom part, that's been carefully tuned over a long period of time, alone, while giving us more-useful-to-the-profile-owner stuff up top.  Nice job balancing all that.  Just one thing: I would like to see the number of profile views.  (Also, I assume that on a site that has main and meta, we'll still have the meta/main profile links up top, near the network profile?)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, thanks!  And yep, the meta/main links are still there on "normal" sites.

Comment: Tracking progress of every single badge: something that should have been in since version 1. So glad it is added now, and I can't wait until it's network-wide.

Comment: Don't have very interesting numbers on Meta... excited to see what the SO one looks like (and to know what my "next" badge is).

Comment: I actually think it looks great!

Comment: Not bad at all - just had a looksee this morning, very nice - but where is my ice cream?

Comment: Can we have a percentage on the loading bars without hovering over them?

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work! I just started playing, so you'll hear from me again. I really appreciate the "Hide a Community" feature. I had logged into a site by accident and didn't want people to think it reflects my beliefs, but I left it because I couldn't figure out how to cancel just that one account. Now I don't have to!

Comment: @canon [this is the post with the info you want](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here).  Scroll down to "How it works today (and why)"

Comment: AWESOME!! this looks GREAT!!

Comment: I can't really judge this based on my (tiny level of) meta.SE activity (I really *don't* care that it thinks my next most achievable badge here is Critic for example). I'd need to look at how it works on my most active SE site(s). I *think* it might be good, but how could I really tell, unless I can see how it would work on the one I deal with every day? If there was a link on my user pages "check out how the new page would look" ... that would let me give real feedback! I can get some idea from other people's pages, ... but it doesn't really show me the things I am actually most familiar with

Comment: @Jaydles When will these changes be shipped [se] wide?

Comment: Hm..It feels kinda weird for some reason that tag badges [can be your newest badge](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XVjUX.png) even though you can't select them as your "next badge" in the Badges box/tag badge progress is displayed in the left box post-privileges, but I have no suggestion on how to do this better :/

Comment: The new design is cool. The Activity section looks sleek and compact. However, I don't like the Profile page. It's good to see that the profile information has taken the centerspace. That's good. But the top network questions and the list of questions on the site don't look good side by side.

Comment: Is it possible to preview this new look page on other SE accounts, e.g. by manually typing a suitable URL?

Comment: can we please have it now its so prettyyyyy

Comment: Gimmeeeee on SO now

Comment: Looks really goo guys. Plus, it tells me that I need to comment to get the next badge. (Is gamification always a good thing?)

Comment: Really good looking and here after it's very easy for me to check so many stuffs in a single page!!

Comment: Any way to jigger with a link or cookie so that I can see how this would *actually* look on my SO profile? My rep/privileges/badges/etc. there and here on meta are quite different, and while I can get an idea of what I'll end up with, it would be far more useful if I could see what the real result would be. Maybe a link in my SO profile to enable/disable a preview of the beta changes?

Comment: I feel SO is wasting a bit of time. Badge progress reports are not really anything I want to spent time on seeing them. Can I please turn them off completely?

Comment: Great look and feel ... refreshing ... and IMHO rather friendly to mobile devices, too. Well done Dev team!

Comment: @MikeD Did you mean it's working on your mobile device? My iOS and Android apps are both showing the old profile page. I just assumed they haven't been updated yet.

Comment: @NoviceSEMetaGeek, it's always dangerous to estimate shipping dates, but managing expectations can't hurt: There is some unrelated back-end design work on other sites that needs to happen first, plus we're cranking through changes based on the suggestions here, so I think we're hoping for something like 4 weeks until we can push it network wide. A little faster than that is possible, and a *lot* longer is always a risk, but we're hoping to come in a little under a month.

Comment: That's a remarkably elegant piece of writing: beautifully poised, and doing a great job of expectations-management and change-management. Kudos to the author(s).

Comment: Ooooo .... *purty*....

Comment: OMG EYE CANDY!!!

Comment: @Sue if you explicitely enter the URL of your user page then yes ... I admit I was curious *ggg*

Comment: I like it, but would quite like to see how it'll look on another site. Is there a way to see the 'stackoverflow' view?

Comment: ERMAHGERD! How long before this is all over the place?

Comment: Getting a lot of `enter image description here` in this post. I'm betting Jaydles uses tables too. Sheesh! ;^)

Comment: @EnergyNumbers, that's one of the nicest comments I've gotten. We worked hard to make sure it spoke to our best users needs, so I *really* appreciate it.

Comment: Agreed - if change was so well aimed and considered at USERS elsewhere on the Internet then it would be a much, much better place. Thanks so much!

Comment: Keep it up guys, this is just awesome! I can't wait to see how many people I reached on Stack Overflow thanks to that new UI. any ETA? :)

Comment: Looks great. When might we expect it to be rolled out network wide?

Comment: Shut up and take my monyey!

Comment: @ElderGeek 6-8 weeks, I think

Comment: I like this new look very much. At first I was a bit put out, but now, after a few days, it makes the old style look positively archaic, and rather unhelpful.

Comment: At first glance it looks good, however I only really lurk here and so there's not much interesting to see... can I find my comment?

Comment: @Klors what do you mean? what comment you want to find?

Comment: @ShadowWizard one of the things I sometimes need to do on other sites is find a comment that I made in the past to check up on the progress of the related question or something. I found the comment that you responded to just fine, so all is well. :)

Comment: +1 Looks good to me.

Comment: Just stumbled here from EE (noob, frankly). One thing is annoying about this : It doesnt scale on zoom. I use 130% (at times 150 %) zoom by default. And in the new page, i just keep scrolling horizontally. Do something so I dont have to scroll horizontally when I zoom or unzoom ie autofit it.

Comment: I love it! I'm hoping to see it used in other parts of the site!

Comment: I haven't read all the answers etc, but boy, I'd love it if you changed the bottom bit to show your most *recent* answers/questions (especially unanswered questions), rather than your highest ranked ones. Again, those don't often change, whereas it's surprisingly hard to navigate your way to "that question I asked yesterday that I'm not sure has been answered yet".

Comment: As a "new" registered user I had to take the Tour first to see what is the next reachable badge. I think it's useful for new users. I love the style as well, great work.

Comment: @SteveBennett I think you can have that now.  Each section has a sort.  Pick "newest". I think it's even "sticky" so it'll show that sort when you come back.

Comment: Kudos on a great profile revamp !!! It does look awesome.

Comment: @jaydles it's not sticky, that's the problem

Comment: I downvoted this question because it told me I had to, to get the next badge ("Critic"). This might not be how you want this to work. But I don't care, I got a shiny! Hey, why didn't I get a shiny? I did my "first downvote" just like it said! I'll try downvoting some comments and answers, too...

Comment: I like it. IT SHINY...

Comment: **(1)** I'm a little annoyed that I had to scan up and down and meander around to realize this is only released on meta.se, for heavens sake please put a notice on your post sake that this is only for meta.se **(2)** I think I won't really be able to get a feel for this new page if it isn't on a site I'm active on. Here I have 682 rep. On SO I have 12K, so if one looks at this new feature where it's more applicable (where one is active) you'd get better inputs. Methinks you should roll this out on : SO, the Trilogy or the X top active sites to get better feedback.

Comment: I have only bronze badges and there is a too big space between bornze badge sign and the number 4.

Comment: Wow this will soon break the most answers record, nice!

Comment: @gideon: That this is only (currently) deployed on Meta Stack Exchange is in the very first sentence.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce man. A year of no-show and now Meta.SE really confuses me. (I still think it's meta.SO) anyway, sorry :/

Comment: When I look at other people's activity pages, am I seeing the badges they are tracking or the badges that the system thinks they are closest to earning?

Comment: Joining the [tens](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141112/what-is-the-name-for-the-second-decade-in-a-century) with a bang! This is a vast improvement to the very aged old design :) I can't wait for it to hit SO

Comment: Nice looking and great that you are asking for feedback before rolling out across all the sites.

Comment: What has any of this got to do with answering people's questions?

Comment: wow seems pretty awesome :D

Comment: Does this new view fix the serial down voting problem hilited by http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286494/serial-upvoting-reversed-makes-reputation-suspect-for-employers?

Comment: @jmoreno - why would it? This new view is tangential to that feature request. Do you think that a style revamp should address every single issue people have ever had on the page?

Comment: @Oded: No, but Shog9 made a comment that it should be trivial and he would follow up on it, and it wouldn't make sense to fix it on the old page just before moving to the new.  Also, a big part of what this style revamp is is tailoring the view to the audience -- so it seemed like it might be something that was included.

Comment: Best testers in the world !

Comment: It appears that the score with the cool new green long rectangular box has been rolled out on SO.

Comment: Tracking people's progress on privalges and possible new badges' progress... We're stalking people now?

Comment: How close are we, realistically, to seeing this go network-wide?

Comment: SHINY??? *(throws Master Ball)*

Comment: I want it at Code Review. Gimme !!

Comment: Is there a "privileges" link that shows the full privilege table? I'm clicking furiously on "next privilege" to no avail. I'm also bad at finding things.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce - we would like to sort out the major issues brought up in the answers here (only 120 answers so far... so a bunch of things to sort out). These things take time. Making sure the page works across the different themes also takes time.

Comment: its soo fluffy im gonna die

Comment: @Oded people don't read many times. Closed as dupe to prevent confusion and users reporting here and not there. :)

Answer (score 156):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### The "next badge" info can be useless

[image]

`0/0` isn't useful. At all.

Comment: So, (if = 0) {hide()}?

Comment: @Braiam That alone would be problematic. If I only saw the top one, there's a chance I'd go crying on meta about why I don't have it.

Comment: Huh? Zero is just a very low value of one. I can't see how that's confusing at all.

Comment: @TimPost It's not helpful since a boolean value isn't countable.

Comment: I feel like you're missing the whole Zen thing that "0/0" is trying to help you experience. It's the *journey*, man. Okay, some of these are weird. We'll take a look - thx!

Comment: @Jaydles I thought about it. There are two things: (1) stricly boolean badges: then you don't need to show anything at all; (2) badges like curious: the second information would use some helper text, and it doesn't need a progress bar at all.

Comment: @Mooseman well it sure isn't uncountable.

Comment: @Yakk I just meant it isn't countable beyond t/f. There's no trackable progress.

Comment: @Mooseman There is a trackable score. You have _positive_ vs. _negative_. This is expressible as a progress bar with a tick in the middle, red to the left (negative score) and green to the right (positive score). Advantage: Shows if you make progress. Disadvantage: If your score is really bad, it will be really red in the progress bar.

Comment: I would rather see `0/0` than nothing at all.

Comment: `x/x lim x->0 = 1 = 100%` so therefore the bar should be green.

Comment: Have you tried using L'Hôpital's? ;)

Comment: @dav_i but: `0/x lim x->0 = 0 = 0%` D:

Comment: I downvoted this answer, trying to get my "Critic" badge for "first downvote".

Comment: @DewiMorgan Couldn't you have found an answer that *does* deserve a downvote? :o

Comment: @Mooseman: I coulda, and with my current knowledge woulda, but am also kinda glad that I didn't, as that would have failed in a few ways. It wouldn't have illustrated so effectively that this new display encourages gaming the system, and the obvious negative downsides to that; and it wouldn't illustrate the fact that our inability to *undo* a downvote is unadvertised by the new system. An inability which is dumber than rocks, I should add.

Comment: Congratulations on the gold badge!

Answer (score 143):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - not sure when this was fixed, but looks OK to my eyes right now...

The reputation history page doesn't have a wide enough area for the time to be shown in relative form and causes it to collapse onto a second line:

> [image: Reputation History]

Comment: And yet Upvote has masses of space...

Comment: This would be so super aligned with flexbox. :)

Comment: Or just not using a `width` CSS tag, but a `min-width` tag

Answer (score 134):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

For higher privileges, reputation looks weird without commas:

[image]

Can we commaficate it?

[image]

Comment: Here, you go, you dropped these: ((

Comment: This form of digit grouping is somewhat specific to certain cultures (most Europeans will wonder about a hundredth or a rep point). [Using thin spaces seems to be the more universally accepted solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping).

Comment: Spacing looks French to me. Using commas are acceptable and so are full stops. I would not think hundredths if I saw 20,123 nor if I saw 20.123 - but then I am European and used to US ways of writing numbers.

Comment: Well, apparently someone has to decide the digit grouping, and since SE is a US company, I can live with comma (even though I was born in a country with full-stop). Nevertheless, most users (citation needed) already know that rep is always in whole number.

Comment: I am from an English speaking EU country and the full stop *always* initially confuses me when I see it as I only see it very rarely (usually when visiting France) and periods are also usually used in place of decimal points, whereas the comma or thin spaces do not cause confusion. That's just my 2c.

Comment: @Raphael: I have no difficulty reading English numbers with English thousands separators and numbers in my local languages with our local thousands separators.  I'm thinking maybe you just need more experience with multilingual reality.

Comment: Maybe I overstated the relevance of the issue, but the fact is that comma is not universally used in this fashion, whereas (thin) spaces can not be confused for anything else. Hence I think thin spaces would be the better typesetting choice here (and everywhere on the site). (cc @tripleee; I don't have an understanding issue myself, but we have now multiple non-English communities in the network. Don't forget that English-speaking countries are in the minority in the world, both in terms of states and speakers.)

Comment: @Raphael For SO sites in other languages, certainly, number formatting (and sorting, and other locale conventions) should be set up in accordance with the language of the site.  That reasoning does not support using an alternate thousands separator on the English-language site.  In fact, it pretty much dictates using the English standard.

Comment: @tripleee And that seems to be thin space, according to the style manuals quoted on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping). The [SI system also specifies spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#General_rules) as delimiters, for precisely my reasons. Especially for the science sites, adhering to SI standards seems obvious.

Comment: *"Can we commaficate it?"* **commaficate**? Is that even a word? Google gives me four results.

Comment: @Lankymart Probably not, but it's fairly clear what it means. Also, I got the second result for 'commaficate', so it's totally worth it.

Comment: This might help with the wording - [English word for the comma between three digits](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/110693). I would have also accepted **commify** which returns over twelve thousand results *(at point of writing)*.

Comment: It could be commatized instead.

Comment: Just put 19k/20k rep, this is so universal.

Comment: As long as rep does not reach into the millions here, who cares about separators?

Comment: @Lankymart "Commify" sounds.... suspicious.

Comment: @TeemuLeisti I'm just going off what Google says blame them. **Commify** *(12.6K+ results)*, **Commatized** *(700+ results)* and **Commaficate** *(4 results)* - All figures accurate at point of writing.

Comment: @Lankymart At what point does it just become _commatose_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Word play...I like it.

Comment: I would agree with @Raphael, using spaces in lieu of commas. International English and International Standards are a bit more non-native English speaker friendly, whilst still remaining easily understood by Brits, Aussies, Yanks and other native English speaking nationalities alike.

Comment: I'm going to shock you all by pointing out that rep points are imaginary and don't represent anything real. It doesn't matter one English ounce which seperator you use because anyone who misinterprets the value will still get the relative value correct. Use the star of David and nearly everyone would still 'Get It' immediately. The only **absolutely** incorrect thing you could do is use spaces as a separator when using a variable spaced font because it'd be nearly impossible to see. Anyone who doesn't immediately understand that has no place making typography suggestions.

Comment: The comma (or any other separator) looks very strange to me in a fraction. I find the first picture easier to read. The second looks like a list with three numbers in it: 19, 588/20, and 000

Comment: @krowe2 I use thin spaces in my LaTeX documents (not using fixed-width fonts, obviously) all the time, and they are clearly visible. Just hacked in thin spaces as separators on this very site, they are clearly visible (FF 35, Ubuntu). So maybe you want to tone down you self-assured judgement just a little bit. (Or maybe you are just used to crappy typesetting, or you need glasses, I don't know.)

Comment: @Raphael I'm not the one who is self assured here. I'm taking the stance of centuries of refinement in best writing practice; that is the opposite of self assurance. You are the one suggesting a new method of doing things which is based on little more than, 'I liked it when I did it this way for my LaTeX docs'. If you were suggesting that we use a dot then you'd have some precedence but that isn't what you are doing at all. You are taking advantage of the fact that there are two competing choices and trying to insert a third option that has been getting rejected over and over for centuries.

Comment: @krowe2 Have you *read* my comments above? Thin spaces are mentioned by several style guides. I looked at centuries old boxes of (lead) letters, and there were thin spaces, and they were used, too. If you are so sure that you are correct, please give some references -- so far all we have is your word, and that's been suspect because of your tone. (Note that my "references" towards HTML and LaTeX documents were only to disprove your broad "nearly impossible to see" claim (which *is* blatantly wrong), not to suggest that using thin space is good style. References for those are above.)

Comment: Raphael and krowe2: (can't '@' both, so I opted for not referencing anyone) Not to be a smart***, but neither of you are offering any references. Now, on the matter of the comma: I'm used to the dot as thousands separator, since I'm from Spain, but I get never confused about the coma in an English site, just because it's the way of English, and just like you learn that "perro" = "dog", you learn that thousands separation in English is performed with a comma. So yes, I think that would be the right way of doing it.

Comment: @krowe2 995 + 5 = 1? 995/1000 = 995/1?

Comment: @badp Are you suggesting that they switch to using a percentage? That isn't a terrible idea but it doesn't tell you as much. I wouldn't go that way.

Comment: @Raphael I think the best solution would be to localize this. Weather or not it's worth the trouble is another question. I will never accept a space as a proper digit grouping character and I don't think many in the English speaking world would choose that if given a choice. It has so many obvious flaws that I'm not going to spend time arguing this.

Comment: @krowe2 In my experience, if it's not obvious enough to put in about 600 characters, it's probably not obvious or false. But well, if you don't want to offer proof, I can't make you.

Answer (score 93):

I would like the "Newest badge" to be a link to this specific badge:

> [image]

The "Next badge" has a different view/design so less important, but having the standard badge view, I was really expecting the Newest badge to be an actual link.

Comment: And isn't it? Maybe it got [tag:status-completed] in-between...

Comment: At the moment a click opens a popup describing the badge instead of linking to the badge page.

Comment: There's no reason why that popup can't have a link to the actual badge page, though.

Comment: When you say link to the specific badge, what do you mean? (For specific-post-driven badges, like Nice Answer, I think I'd expect it to indicate or point to the relevant post?)

Comment: @Jaydles no, I mean such link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=147336 from there you can reach all relevant posts, if such exists.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, first off, thanks for using my ID in the link - nice touch.  I see - that puts the post you're looking for (the new one that triggered the award) right at the top, but with the rest below. Makes a lot of sense. I'd kind of also like to see a link to the relevant post in the pop-up - they're often old enough that I want to go there, too.  We'll likely do something along these lines, although it might added after it ships network-wide with some other "non-blocker" good ideas.

Comment: @Jaydles thanks a bunch! ;-)

Answer (score 88):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (with you in the next build)

Can we have the `helpful flags` link on the text too instead of on the number only?

Now you need to click very carefully if you have only a few flags.

[image]

Comment: We are discussing internally whether there is a good reason to hide this value from everyone. If not, it might do a comeback.

Comment: You mean: hide it from me too? This is taken from my profile, right?

Comment: No, I mean show it to everyone.

Comment: Ah, okay. So this would become public information? Is it useful to show the declined ratio too?

Comment: That's what we are discussing. Any input welcome - we definitely would like to hear from people what they think.

Comment: @Oded Perhaps post a new question to that effect?

Comment: Posted a question about this here: [Should the number of helpful flags be public to anyone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249981/245360).

Comment: @Oded, when you view another person's profile there is no space between the number and "helpful flags".

Comment: @gunr2171 - thanks for reporting. Fixed in the next build.

Comment: From my experience as a mod: keep the stat private. The main purpose of flags is to keep the site running properly. But even now, we have users who are hung up enough on numbers to protest not because the declining *didn't make sense* but because *it feels like a negative mark on their record*. Making the number public will induce behavior geared towards keeping the record clean even when it interferes with the primary purpose of flag casting and handling, e.g. users not casting when they are unsure, and pressure on mods to never decline.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks for that separate post about whether or not this should be public information. I think it should be private, but as with a number of these issues, I think it merits a separate discussion, and I encourage people to make your opinions known.  Once the new profile is rolled out network-wide, it will be much more difficult to make changes. This is a huge undertaking, and I appreciate how hard everyone is working to address the concerns of the entire SE community! Thanks all!

Answer (score 76):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - not really secret information, as discussed in the related [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249981/should-the-number-of-helpful-flags-be-public-to-anyone).

If someone's next badge is Deputy (or Marshall, probably), I can see how many flags they have: ([balpha's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha?tab=activity))

[image: 61/80 flags for balpha]

This used to be private information, and pending a decision on [Should the number of helpful flags be public to anyone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249981/should-the-number-of-helpful-flags-be-public-to-anyone), might as well be hidden.

Comment: A good question: why *do* they hide the number of helpful flags? It's not exactly private or sensitive information, and it's already publicly visible information when a user does receive the Deputy or Marshal badge. So, why not always display the number and only link it for that user and moderators? If there's a line specifically dedicated to that statistic in that right box that will otherwise always be empty, just show it.

Comment: @animuson - we are thinking this over. There might not be a good reason to hide it.

Comment: I agree with @Oded that showing the precise number of flags can have problems. Knowing that someone is a "flagger" is not that much a problem. But the precise number can allow for some reverse engineering of their behaviour.

Comment: MSE question for this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249981/should-the-number-of-helpful-flags-be-public-to-anyone

Comment: @yo' What reverse behavioral reverse engineering can be done?

Comment: @skrrgwasme IMHO flags are confidential (much more than votes), and from precise number of them, you can know when the user flagged something. I don't consider it good.

Comment: @yo' I agree that you can see *when* a user flagged something, but not *what*. If I downvote and flag a post without leaving a comment, there is no way the author of that post can know it was me that did so. Do you see a way to for visible flag counts to allow a post's author to associate flags with an account if the flagger doesn't leave a comment?

Comment: Flagging isn't always bad like downvoting, which also isn't always bad. Downvoting is arguably worse since it lowers rep, which is important to newbies. Flagging to close only hurts visitors when the reason is bad (like Ubuntu questions that mention the version being closed due to a new version being out despite the issue persisting in that new version).

Answer (score 70):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: inconsistent accept colour]

Inconsistent accept background greens make kittens cry.

Comment: Inconsistent how? "95" is 26% higher than 76, so it's  26% deeper green, as it should be.  (Okay, so applying numeric measures to terms like "deeper color" MAY give away that I'm just making crap up at this point.)

Comment: You just wanted the kittens to stop crying, it's understandable! And don't listen to Joel, *we* care what you think. Unless we disagree, then I make no promises.

Comment: I'm not crying!  I'm just parsing onions with regex.

Comment: @SomeKittens, do you have a formula for dicing? [I know I should ask this on SO, or Seasoned Advice, but I've no time for research]

Comment: Just completed... But I loved the previous accept color!

Comment: @nicael Well that's a separate issue, I just wanted them to be consistent, whatever colour they were :P

Comment: Ok. Then I request there that those both colors should be **old dark green**.

Comment: @nicael -1 I actually like the lighter color

Comment: @Tim I disagree. Does it not make sense that the smaller box should be a more compressed, concentrated green?

Answer (score 63):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Yay, I can hide communities now! I've just tested it with my Lifehacks account - added it to hidden communities.

However: It's properly hidden in the "Profile" tab:

> [image]

...but it can be seen in the new "Activity" tab:

> [image]

Comment: Excellent catch!

Answer (score 48):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Please add a more useful tooltip for helpful flags.

[image]

The "posts edited" tooltip is good:

> Total number of edits made to improve existing posts

The "votes cast" tooltip is good:

> Total number of up, down, or accept votes cast

But the helpful flags tooltip is just

> Helpful flags

I propose it be changed to

> Total number of raised flags marked useful

---

Also:

```
if(flags == 1) str = "helpful flag"; else str = "helpful flags";
```

Comment: I see pluralization bug!

Comment: +1 for good documentation

Comment: @nicael The screenshot was taken from the [original post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/202832), but I appended a note of that here.

Comment: It was agreed somewhere that SE doesn't use singular for the case when a counter happens to be equal to one. I don't like it either, but I understand the decision.

Comment: So... `0 flag` but `1 flags`?

Comment: @KRyan [status-fixed-typo]

Comment: [status-fifteen-char-smiley-face] :)

Answer (score 45):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please make "posts edited" and "votes cast" links to the relevant pages:

> [image]

1. "posts edited" would link to [activity → revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=revisions)
2. "votes cast" would link, only when viewing own profile of course, to [my votes tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes).

Comment: Helpful flags, also.

Comment: @Frank It is already a link.

Comment: Oh. Right.‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Answer (score 44):

This text in the edit profile "About you" box is confusing and I'm not quite sure what it's trying to say:

[image: confusing sentence]

> "Tell us more about you and your the software that powers the Stack Exchange network background"

Markov chain?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too and my the wondered what the hell.

Comment: In seriousness, I assume it's supposed to just say "Tell us more about you and your background", and "the software that powers the Stack Exchange Network" got pasted in by accident somehow.

Comment: Lol! That's hilarious :D

Comment: The idea behind this was to just steal the "what is this site about" text and insert it directly into that space. So on Stack Overflow, for example, it would read as "Tell us more about you and your programming background." It obviously doesn't work with Meta's on-topic text.

Comment: @animuson I think Meta is a special case.

Answer (score 43):

Doesn't "Go get it" encourage people to do bad things?

E.g. for "Sportsmanship":

[image]

When I click it, it brings me to my answers. So is it supposed that now I'll start clicking each of my answers and up voting other answers on that page? That's not the purpose of voting... I thought our votes should be based on the contents of the post.

Comment: Don't do badges that in general? I think there is not much harm in it (opposed to the current situation).

Comment: @Pat Yes, but, as for me, I often vote without thinking about getting this badge...

Comment: If you are searching for badges, you won't need the button. If not, I think it is a useful way to encouraging good behavior by pointing people to the way how to get something.

Comment: I agree with @nicael. Although it may not affect established users, new users who see this type of prompt are more likely to upvote garbage.

Comment: We've never had this type of prompt before...so let's see what happens rather than assuming what will happen.

Comment: @Laura Okay, but only if you track actions taken shortly after clicking the go-get-it button, so we have data to make an informed conclusion.  (e.g., are users more likely to upvote bad posts (downvoted by other users) after clicking the button?)

Comment: @PatrickHofman But so far, they were "little surprises", like your company giving you golden watch after you work there hard for 50 years. You don't hunt for golden watches, but they make you happy. SE should not encourage people to hunt for badges.

Comment: @yo' then there shouldn't be badges in the first place.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There should IMHO, similarly as there should be golden watches to very good employees. But it shouldn't be something you hunt for.

Comment: @yo' I thought employees hunted for golden watches by not taking jobs with other employers? Seriously though, what is "bad" about upvoting other answers, or any other "badge-earning" behavior? Badges are, I think, designed to encourage *good* behavior.

Comment: @yo' they weren't "little surprises" if you were a badge hunter... there was already a page that shows them all and explains how to get them. So if you were a badge hunter before then you already probably found out how to get them all and so this changes nothing. The only thing that remains to be seen is if it encourages people who weren't badge hunters to become badge hunters.

Comment: Personally, I've kind of been in limbo on this site for a while, not moving ahead on many fronts.  As such I would love this feedback.  But then, I'm an adult and rational person and would get not much kick from badge hunting, so maybe that's just me!

Comment: @Laura: Review queues have the progress bars for badges and such integrated in the UI. Until now that was the place in the UI where most focus was put on getting badges, on artificial incentives. Bad and robo reviews have been big problems. I think that's not surprising. When you put all the focus on the badges/..., that's where people's focus will be. People do stuff for badges and you hope that it happens to be good for the site. Previously they did stuff that was good for the site and maybe happened to get a badge for it.

Comment: The next badge prompt for me here on Meta is "Citizen Patrol".  It's no fun knowing I have to go out looking for something I can downvote just so I can get a new badge to show up in that section.  (Oops, I meant flag, thanks nicael!)

Comment: @Jan it's awarded for flagging, not downvoting btw :)

Answer (score 41):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

<s>There's a green number next to my rep in the activity view. It looks like it should be how much rep i got today, but it's been consistently off by 20.</s>

[image]

And i can't just blame caching here, because it's always off by 20.

---

Update: Upon clarification from Oded, it's the amount of reputation earned since visiting the rep tab in the profile (activity). OK then, that makes sense. How about a tooltip explaining that?

---

Update: This has now been added, but i'm seeing the tooltip twice. One the default, and one a custom SE one:

[image: double tooltip]

Comment: It is the value since you visited the reputation tab of the activity page.

Comment: @Oded Ah, OK. Now can you add a tooltip explaining that?

Comment: This confused me the first time I saw it too

Comment: Reminds me of the number in favorites tab and highlighted posts when I visit it. Although I read what they mean several times, I keep forgetting. A tooltip would be really great everywhere “since last visit to a specific page” stats are displayed.

Comment: +! for the tooltip then...

Comment: Yeah, noticed the double tooltip. That's fixed for the next build.

Answer (score 39):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but strangely, the preview isn't shown if browsing from mobile (From Galaxy S5 in Chrome in my case) (please comment if you can repro this strange behaviour).

As you are modifying profile editor anyway, can "About me" preview be added please?

> [image]

Answer (score 37):

1. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) <strike>The text used for the "Protect Questions" privilege has a lonely bracket;</strike>

   > [image]
2. The text used to congratulate me I'd surpassed 10k didn't read right;

   > [image]

   Either "Thanks to your efforts, you *have.*.. Access to moderator tools", or "Thanks to your efforts, you can... Access <s>to</s> moderator tools"

Comment: I've lost the pop-up on my own one, but **the recently-earned privilege needs to be linked** to the appropriate description. I.e. currently the `Access to moderator tools` on that second screenshot does not link anywhere.

Comment: The lost parenthesis actually exists on other badge descriptions as well.

Comment: "Thanks to your efforts, you can... Established user" <-- This did make soo little sense that I did not realize it should be read as 1 phrase, with a descriptive privilege, until reading this answer. http://imgur.com/7yF8COJ

Comment: Maybe “can” → “gained” improves the situation. But “…, you gained Established user” still sounds bad. Better avoid incorporating privilege names into a sentence, or rename them for this purpose.

Comment: If it's a generic phrase for all privileges, `Thanks to your efforts, you earned` is probably a lot better. Otherwise, why not craft individual lead-up sentences for each?

Answer (score 36):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as I see, but [another problem came up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/250285#250285)

Can my top tag have the tag badge shown (silver in my case) if I have it (as it's done in the "profile" tab for "top tags")?

> [image]

Answer (score 33):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

by changes of just 1 reputation you show the same number (263 below) twice. Looks a bit incorrect having the same value two times on different positions in a graph.

[image]

The same number can be repeated three times if there were no reputation changes in the period:

[image]

Comment: I would assume that it's 263.5 rounded down, and I agree it's a bug then.

Comment: but two times 264 also wouldn't be nice. I would leave the middle blank in this case.

Comment: Easy fix: post a bug report, get upvotes that change the scaling of the graph. It's a self-fixing bug.

Answer (score 30):

The badge progress popup shouldn't say "how do **you** get it" and "go get it" shouldn't be displayed if the profile in which I open this popup isn't mine (I mean, eh, I am not Pëkka but nicael, but Pëkka's profile says I can get this badge):

> [image]

Moreover, I have this badge already :) Also I tried getting this badge for Pëkka, as the popup says, but failed :D

Comment: even if it would not be a sensible bug report (which it _is_), I would upvote for "I tried getting this badge for Pëkka, as the popup says". Would be funny if system indeed worked that way (it probably does to some extent - eg, other users can help one get tag badges by voting up posts in respective tags)

Answer (score 29):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - we are now using an image size the is supported by imgur, so it gets properly cropped.

### My face is being smashed.

[image: Profile pic is being resized weird.]

Comment: Whoa that's weird. It links to http://i.stack.imgur.com/RUyLX.jpg?s=36&g=1 instead of http://i.stack.imgur.com/RUyLX.jpg?s=164&g=1. Did you upload a non-square avatar?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure. It looks correct everywhere else though, including the new profile's Edit Profile page. Something is amiss!

Comment: Can confirm this ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/dCvfWc1.png)). I uploaded a non-square picture. It gets cropped correctly everywhere but on the top-right of the tabs `Activity` and `Edit profile & Settings`.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed?

Comment: @AustinHenley It works correctly for me

Answer (score 27):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When I hover my mouse on the graph, labels are shown on the top left of the page...

[image: Graph bug]

See the label on the black sidebar? My cursor was somewhere at the beginning of the green line. I guess it is just a problem of relative/absolute position of elements, the label is moving the same way I move my mouse over the graph :)

On Firefox 36.0, Windows 8.1

Comment: Same here: Firefox and Windows, also adblock and Ghostery if that's relevant.

Comment: FF 35.0.1, Win 7. Same

Comment: This was posted already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249964/202832

Comment: @Mooseman Oh, didn't see it. Actually I looked at captures to see if it was reported...

Comment: Also on Ubuntu, FF 37.0a2

Answer (score 26):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The `Learn more` button runs over the dialog bounds when running from a iPad:

[image]

Comment: happens in my desktop browser (Opera 12) as well

Comment: I like the way that looks.

Comment: It must be tempting to mark that as [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: I think it would look better shoved down a few pixels

Comment: So if we like the way it looks, should be we downvoting, not upvoting?

Comment: @Cole: You should definitely up vote ;). Whether we like it or not is not important. It's just a bug.

Answer (score 26):

The **Hide Communities** section shows 12 communities, but I can't tell how those 12 were selected.  It includes many communities that I have joined but have gained zero rep.  I suggest it display your top 12 communities in terms of rep.  It'd also be nice to show the rep (and possibly your number of questions and answers) next to each community.

Comment: Totally agree, better yet take it initially from the customized "your communities" list in the top bar, then complete to 12 if needed sorting by reputation.

Comment: Yeah, this page behaves super-weird if you have more than 12 sites.  We'll definitely make some changes to this UI to address what you're describing.

Comment: @Jaydles, I'd rather it just listed all sites, rather than making me go somewhere else to remember which sites I'm on. Also, what happens if I choose to hide the site I'm currently on? (I haven't dared try)

Comment: @Jaydles any updates a month later?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, we're cranking to ship the page network-wide, probably this week.   This update will probably come in a second pass a bit later.

Comment: @Jaydles thanks, fair enough. :)

Answer (score 26):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - There was some inconsistency in selection and ordering of tags - between Top Tags and the selected top tag in the activity page.

[image]

There seems to be an inconsistency between what different parts of my profile think my 'top tag' is. I presume the actual 'Top tag' is the most intelligent measure, but the inconsistency is a bit odd.

(N.B. Third variation edited in later.)

And to sneak a second one in - is there a way to set a tag-badge as your next target that I've missed? That's what I'd want to do on my SO profile!

Comment: The Top tag counts the *score on both questions and answers*, while the the Tags section only show *score from answers*. (in your case, your [tag:ios-app] has total score of 47, and 7 from answers only, you can hover the tag score for this info).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT - I'd assumed something like that, but the inconsistency is odd. (With the third variation as well!) All these lists of "Top Tags" should be ordered in the same way - or clearly NOT in "Top Tag" order: e.g. Alphabetical.

Comment: Would also like to track a tag badge for my next target.  Probably closer to one of those than any of the others I can track.

Comment: There was some inconsistency in selection and ordering of tags - between Top Tags and the selected top tag in the activity page. That is now resolved.

Answer (score 26):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

The new "Badges" section is more colorful and I like it, but is there a reason why there is no background color and border if there are no badges for particular rank?

Aside of that, I personally prefer "0" or "-" (dash) instead of "—" (notice the length) when there are no badges. As of current, without color and border, I thought that as horizontal line at first and was confused.

> [image: Jaydles's badges]
>
> <sup>[Jaydles's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles) badges on [Scimonter's feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/249960#249960)</sup>
>
> [image: my badges]
>
> <sup>My badges</sup>

Comment: +1, side-by-side, the two designs make sense, but looking at my own profile, it took a moment to work out why "GOLD" was badly underlined...

Answer (score 26):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - I appreciate the thought, but the graph on this page is not meant to be a fully detailed graph, that's why we have the reputation sub tab...

These tool-tips are really cool:

[image]

But given that the graph is super-small (and the tooltip often covers the axis labels), it would be cool to have the month/year in the tooltip too, so instead of "2,464" it would read "Jun '14 2,464".

Comment: @oded then why have tooltips to begin with? :)

Comment: @badp - adding the date would make it overly busy. Just rep strikes a good balance, I think.

Comment: @oded I agree both can't work but in general what would be more useful is being able to click on the small graph to open the reputation audit page of your profile in its entire glory

Comment: @badp - you mean like it does already?

Answer (score 25):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - The bug has been fixed. The percentage will display properly now.

The hoverbox for the Electorate badge doesn't have the progress bar for the %-of-votes-on-questions working correctly:

[image]

At the moment, 54% of my votes are on questions. Not 0%.

Either the % bar should be hidden (which makes some sense, since %-of-votes-on-questions is a value that can fluctuate both up and down), or it should actually show the % of votes on questions (or maybe `max(25%, %-of-votes-on-questions)`).

Comment: Hmm - it's looking like some badges where the second bar is not a "standard" count (percents, "positive record", etc.) are displaying incorrectly - we'll check it out.

Comment: I wonder if this is being counted as 0.54 / 25, rounded down.

Comment: @doppelgreener, it's 54/25 not 0.54/25...

Comment: @PythonMaster I know it is. We're talking about a bug though, and a percentage. Percentages are usually most conveniently stored as a decimal: 0.54 to represent 54%. If they didn't convert it back to an integer form we'd get the above bug

Answer (score 21):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - given that you already *have* the reputation in a big black font, adding it *again* is redundant. So we put the actual rep required.

I would like to see the progress (1,098/2,000) text added next to Next Privilege

[image]

in the same way that progress (46/80) text already appears next to Next Badge
[image]

I know that I can already see it by hovering my mouse over the next privilege but if progress count is there for Badges why not Privileges too.

Answer (score 21):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - we've done a bunch of work on this, though the mobile pages are still a work in progress.

Currently it's kinda difficult to explore profile pages using mobile web (click "mobile" link in the bottom and check the profile page) , please don't forget to fix it :)

E.g.: Summary:

> [image]

Questions:

> [image]

Comment: I think the lack of responsiveness is expected for the moment.

Comment: +1 so it will not be forgotten. Accessing the profile page from my mobile gave me the tiny-font zoomed-out view.

Comment: We've put in a bunch of work into the mobile view (and dropped some features that are in the full site view - both in consideration of low bandwidth on mobile networks and to do with the page aesthetics on a mobile device).

Answer (score 20):

The text of how can I earn the badge is taken directly from the badge description, but it sounds incorrect under the heading "How can you **earn** the badge". E.g.: "Edit**ed** and answer**ed**".

> [image]

Should be "Edit and answer" in this case.

Answer (score 19):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - I appreciate the sentiment. At least visually speaking, this view just don't fit anywhere on the activity page. We might do that in the future, but this doesn't change often enough for one to keep seeing on ones own profile.

The rarest badges list on the profile view is nice. It would be cool to have that on the activity view as well. (Image of [Jaydles's badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles).)

[image: Rarest badges]

Comment: Agreed that it's cool, but I don't think this changes frequently enough to be on the activity page.

Comment: Instead of / as well as the data achieved, could we have the number of other people who have it?

Comment: FWIW, [Data Explorer query for rarest badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/34248/badges-to-aspire-to) overall for a given site.

Answer (score 18):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Nitpicky, but there's inconsistent capitalization in the tabs at the top (some mod-only):

[image]

Specifically "Edit profile & Settings", "Account info", "mod", and "Network profile". I think the standard elsewhere on the site is to do all lowercase for tabs, but if we want to keep the capitalization here then "Profile" (both places), "Info" and "Mod" should be capitalized IMO.

Comment: On the subject, is there something better that can be used than "Edit Profile & Settings"? It looks really odd having two tabs that are just a word and then this long four-word tab right after. If not just "Settings" why not something like "Edit/Settings"?

Comment: Or even just Edit

Answer (score 17):

My recommended "Next Badge" is Excavator, which I guess I am "close" to earning in some absolute sense, but it is not really useful to show "progress" in a badge that I only need to take one action to earn. I would suggest instead recommending the badge with the greatest **percentage** of progress.

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - with you in the next build.

When I click `Track the next one` after having completed a badge, I get the message:

> Unable to load popup - please try again

[image: screenshot]

The following error shows up in the console:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/activity/badge-card/next-badge-popup?userId=209031&_=1424710363634
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/activity/badge-card/next-badge-popup?userId=209031&_=1424710659111 404 (Not Found)

[image: console]

Comment: @Oded: I'm still seeing this.

Comment: @Oded: re-raised as [Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250476)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thanks. Will take another look :(

Answer (score 14):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - the tooltip doesn't stop the mouse from moving and fades out when the mouse moves out of the graph. I don't see the problem a delays is supposed to solve.

### Please delay showing the tooltip in the graph

The tooltip shouldn't appear when my cursor is merely passing through. I think something like

```
on mouseover
    wait 100ms || 500ms
    if still mouseover
        show tooltip
```

should be used. Note also the `mouseout` event isn't always captured when this happens, leaving the tooltip there until the mouse returns.

Comment: I'd tend to disagree, at least with the suggested time - I absolutely hate "point & wait" interfaces because you never know if there's no hover event for the current location, or you just haven't waited long enough. The timeout should be 100ms at most.

Comment: @IMSoP 100ms shouldn't leave too many fp's. Post edited.

Comment: @IMSoP [UX.SE seems to think otherwise.](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/358/how-long-should-the-delay-be-before-a-tooltip-pops-up)

Comment: @Qix That accepted answer is rather poor if you ask me - it doesn't actually give any UX reasoning for the 500ms delay. It's strongest argument is an assumption that the designers of those libraries maybe thought about UX when setting their default. The other answers agree with me that an excessive delay is poor UX, and one links a library (hoverIntent) with a default delay of 100ms.

Comment: There's a great [plugin](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent) for that.

Answer (score 14):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - this page is about recent activities, not about what you want others to see (that's for the profile page).

1)  I like that I can choose my next badge. Can we also get a similar ability to choose which of our badges we want to display either on the Top Badges section, or the new Badges box on the Activity section?

[image]

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) - we like this, just need to find a good way to implement it.

2) Can the badge boxes be clickable and take me to a filtered list of my badges? I was wondering what were my 3 gold badges, and my first instinct was to click on the box to see them.

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) - this has come up already when we got feedback for the profile page. We are still looking at a good way to represent all the wanted information there in a good way.

3) On the Top Network Posts, can we get a border or something around the reputation number so it doesn't look like it's part of the title?

[image]

Overall though, I think I like it. Nice job with it! :)

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is no page title when in "My Logins" or "Hide Communities" sections of "Edit profile and settings", it's just showing the raw URL as the title. (it's fine in all other sections)

Answer (score 13):

I vote to change the helpful flags line to something around "No flags yet" if the user hasn't flagged anything. It makes it look like I have done things, but none were useful.

[image: picture of me without flags]

Comment: Yes, but changed "Hasn't flagged anything" to "doesn't have any helpful flags". If a user hasn't flagged anything, "0 helpful flags" on the profile might be a good nudge to get them flagging. If they've flagged but have been declined, this is just rubbing it on their noses.

Comment: @E.P. I like that even better. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't say that I closed this, I was just expanding to what @E.P said above.

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - with you in the next build

Halp! Upvotes are black instead of green! Love new borders btw.

> [image]

Comment: @Oded thx!  Then you can tag [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287252/let-the-upvotes-be-green)  with [status-completed] too (and maybe migrate to MSE as it appears to relate to a bunch of sites)

Comment: @Oded poke ^^^^

Comment: @Oded poke poke pokity poke ^^^

Comment: @hichris123 that is a radical change... :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard ["radical"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality)

Answer (score 12):

I like the "People Reached" addition; makes me feel useful and warm inside. But the tooltip only tells me that it counts view on my questions and my highly ranked answers. What constitutes a highly ranked answer? Is is based on number of votes (if so, how is that scaled between large and small SE sites?)? Is it only answers where mine is either accepted or highest voted?

Perhaps the tooltip can be updated to clarify what "highly ranked" means. Or, and this might be good to, if you already know which answers are highly ranked to count their views, maybe the people reached indicator could link to all of the posts it includes (or at least the answers, since it counts all of the questions and those can be found on the questions page). That way any visitors can see your top contributions in one list, you could check up on the number of views; really it's just giving us more information (knowledge is power).

Comment: Added note, 1 upvote on this was enough to increase my "People Reached" score. I'd not have considered an answer with 1 vote among 22 other answers to be highly ranked, so clarification of some sort is definitely required

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/259693

Comment: @Scimonster Hmmm... That explains almost everything except why I got a higher impact score after 1 vote on this answer. It was not highest voted, not accepted, not >5 votes, and not in the top 20% of vote count (unless referring to my personal vote count). Either way, the tool-tip in the new user profile should definitely give more info for all those people who don't know where the explanation in mother meta might be

Answer (score 12):

Could we get a placeholder or tooltip to indicate what types of links are required for the Profile Web Presence settings

When I went to add my Stack Overflow Careers Page, I got the following error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - The Stack Overflow Careers link or username entered does not appear to be a valid Stack Overflow Careers link or username.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried the following links before it finally working on the third.

- https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/266832
- https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/160667
- https://careers.stackoverflow.com/kylemit

The issue is that most people when they click on their profile are going to be taken to one of the first two links first when they're signed in.  It might not be obvious to use the bottom link, even though it's the only one of the three that's publically accessible.

Comment: It is expected to be a link to your public profile. I will amend the description.

Comment: @Oded: Imho it should simply accept all variants that identify the user, and transform it into the profile link automagically

Comment: Agree with automagic. Or perhaps an auto-complete UI linked up to an API on Careers - should be pretty to engineer since you run both sites!

Comment: @oded, I know "Magic" is easy to ask for and hard to do, but I'd try to aim at making it accept any variant that we can be pretty darn sure can only suggest one possible user, and then show the public page no matter which one they pasted.

Comment: @Jaydles: Doesn't Stack Exchange already have information linking your profiles to your SO Careers page?  Shouldn't it just be a checkbox, indicating whether or not to include a link?

Comment: @AmeliaBR - not that simple. Not everyone has a SO Careers page. Not everyone who does have one has it set to public display. We are working on making this much simpler.

Comment: @Oded, thus the checkbox

Comment: @KyleMit - a checkbox isn't enough. Say you check it, but don't have a SO Careers link, or it isn't linked to your account. What should happen?

Comment: @oded What should happen?  Probably a pop-up warning that says "We can't find an SO Careers profile associated with your account.  If you have an SO Careers page, go to the settings page [link to settings] and ensure that it is visible and associated with your Stack Exchange login."  But I understand that getting different computer servers to talk to each other is not always as easy as human logic expects it to be...

Comment: @AmeliaBR - we are working on making this as simple as possible. If we do know you have a careers profile, we will be able to tell if it is private/public and prompt accordingly. If we don't know (either because it isn't linked or because you don't have one), we will be able to offer different guidance (link the profile or create one, for instance). The backend work to make this possible is in progress.

Answer (score 12):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

That "*Select your next badge*" window is nice and encourages badge-hunting very well :-)

Three improvements I'd like to see:

- the edit symbol that brings you to the window does not have a tooltip
- it's not clear whether the "selected" badge is selected forever or just for the current view, and especially whether this selection is publicly visible or not.
- the selection table has progress bars for each badge in the background. I'd also like to see the numbers (that would be shown when selected) directly in the overview, maybe on-hover only: There's a huge difference between 5/10 and 300/600 which is otherwise not apparent before selecting the badge.

Comment: +1 just not your suggestion 3 please, 1+2 are good.

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - we have done a  bunch of work on mobile views for these pages. We dropped some features that exist in the non-mobile views (to save bandwidth, for mobile aesthetics and mobile UX).

**Desperately needs phone-friendliness!**

This is what my Activity page looks like on my phone (all screenshots are from Chrome on Android; first two at default zoom):

[image: Activity on Samsung S4]

That's not very readable.  (These uploaded images are large even after I shrunk the captured images; imagine on a phone.)  For comparison, here's what my profile page on another site looks like:

[image: Old profile on Samsung S4]

Ah, much better -- I can read that.

The new Profile page has the same problem as the new Activity page -- it's trying to scale the whole thing to my 4.8" screen.  When you rolled out the new profile I assumed that was temporary and that a mobile view would be coming, but it sounds like you're getting ready to roll this out and I don't see that yet.

Also, the layout on the reputation tab on my phone is a little wonky (but is ok in a full-size browser):

[image: cramped scores and timestamps on reputation tab]

Comment: [I already reported it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250114/259214).

Comment: We've done a bunch of work on mobile views in the last couple of days. Hope you like it.

Comment: @Oded oh that's *much* better -- thanks!

Comment: Is the reputation tab still wonky for you? Or is that looking better? (if not, mind specifying browser/os/device?)

Comment: @Oded The reputation tab now looks nicely aligned.  For downvotes the word "downvoted" runs *right* up against the title of the post (Android, Chrome 40.0.2214.109, default zoom), but it doesn't overlap -- so that's information, not a complaint.  But all the weird staggering stuff is gone now.

Comment: Huh, comment entry on MSE is no longer a fixed-width font?  That's new...

Answer (score 12):

That's a pity that I can't track tag badge progress before reaching the last privilege (in other words, before 20k).

Can I have an ability to choose between tracking a privilege and tracking the progress towards the tag badge, which is much more important and interesting for me?

Answer (score 12):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) - we would love to do this, but there are so many things happening with these pages right now, that it would take some time to get to, possibly in a future iteration of the pages.

I only do minimal FOSS contributions to Github. My main FOSS projects are all hosted on BitBucket.

I would very much like a dedicated field for BitBucket, but doing so will inadvertently result in everyone asking for a field for their favorite FOSS repository.

So, rather than overloading the Edit Profile page with an endless list of FOSS repository hosting services, what if the "Web Presence" part is built like Google+'s "Links" portion of the Profile>About page? It's a 3-part 'card' containing:

1. Profiles -- links to one's profile page on various websites.
2. Contributor to -- links to one's works: articles, FOSS projects, whathaveyou
3. Links / Others -- sites not falling into categories (1) or (2) above

Each category starts out empty; clicking on an ajax-powered "Add link" linky adds a new field where one can simply type the name of a link, and the link proper.

Comment: Making this extensible will also help with the non-programming sites -- on Arqade you can link to your Steam profile, for example.

Comment: This is planned, just not for the current version (had to draw the line somewhere...)

Comment: @Oded ah, thanks for the clarification! May I suggest to add a list of "planned features" somewhere, linked from the metaQ?

Comment: When I say planned, I mean, one day in the future. Not in the immediate future - this depends on other projects and dev resources, so can be a long way away.

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - the color of the "recommended" badge has been updated, but we will not be changing the progress bars at this time.

The *Select your next badge* pop-up has the text "recommended" positioned at the top-right of the closest to being awarded badge. For me, this is the Inquisitive badge, but I edited the text to "Research Assistant" to show how this text's background is far too close to the badge name text:

[image: Recommended]

I also feel that grey-on-grey action is a bit ugly, too. Perhaps that could also be green to match the ticks on already-unlocked badges?

Actually, the more I look at it the uglier it becomes. Why does the text need to be positioned on top of the progress bar anyway? Why do the progress bars have to be the same colour as the badge they're representing? I feel doing it with a thinner progress bar and displaying the actual badge makes it look so much nicer.

#### How it currently looks

[image: Current design]

#### How I propose it's done instead

[image: Proposed design]

Comment: What about tag badges? Couldn't those run into the `recommended` square in your proposal?

Comment: [Related suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250010/168244)...

Answer (score 11):

I can't find the ***age*** of user's anymore. Checked both the Profile and Activity tabs, but not there.

Where did it go?

Comment: Cheese stolen as part of [Profile Page makeover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253460/148310).

Answer (score 10):

How often are the badge progress numbers updated? My votes today aren't yet reflected.

*Blame it on caching™* is an acceptable answer.

Comment: They are updated daily.

Comment: @Oded: Might want to note that somehow in the UI, otherwise I think you can count on a fair number of people complaining on Meta that their numbers aren't moving.

Comment: @Oded, is that for all badges, or all except the current goal?  I thought the one currently selected updated much more often, but the "chooser" was showing a daily cached value?

Comment: @Jaydles - I believe the design was for daily updates. Jarrod is looking at making it much more frequent.

Comment: @Oded, great- thanks!

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - No more 0/0 bar now

I didn't earn the Curious badge, because I don't have a positive question record. If I'm not mistaken, this means I will never earn the Curious badge (unless I would delete questions). Yet, it appears as the 'Next badge' in my activity tab.

Also, at first, I didn't get why I didn't have the badge: I have 18/5 and 0/0. The popup isn't very clear in this border case.

[image]

Comment: You are mistaken: by asking more well-received questions you can get the badge. The overall record improves in the process.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat okay, (thanks!), but in that case this popup is _really_ misleading. It doesn't show any progress.

Comment: We are debating this badge (and others like it) - we really don't like how it displays and are looking into alternative visualizations (may have to drop it for now if we can't find something reasonable).

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Is there any way for a user to track progress towards tag badges, before they have maxed out all possible privileges?  It's a neat feature, and something I'd be more interested in than the site badge progress.

Maybe it could be something that shows up specifically on the "tags" or "badges" sub-pages.

Comment: I agree. I recently answered a [tag:shell] question on SO just to get the bronze badge there.

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When hovering over the reputation graph, the tooltip that shows the exact reputation number is very far top and left of the actual graph. So much so, that it goes above my window screen when hovering around like the middle point of the graph, and goes even further above the farther right I go.

Does this when using either IE or firefox (latest vers) on windows 8.1

Comment: Which browser & OS are you using, and do you have any sort of zoom enabled? Chrome on a Mac displays the rep tooltip right on top of the rep line...

Comment: I see the same on IE 9 on Windows 7 Enterprise. (No, I do not have the option to get a better browser.)

Comment: @Laura Firefox on Linux has the same effect.

Comment: Can reproduce on Firefox 35.0.1 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Chrome on Linux is fine (same as what @Laura described)

Comment: Same problem on Firefox 35.0.1 under Windows 7.

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - the avatar is bigger now.

That's great that avatar is clickable! I didn't notice it at first. Can the name be made clickable too please?

> [image]

Comment: What's the point of a clickable avatar anyways?

Comment: Agree, currently they're both links to the profile page.

Comment: Yes, but they should both be the same.

Comment: @Tim yep, I agree.

Comment: @Scimonster, I asked the same thing when someone internal asked for the Avatar link to be put back in. It's useful as a quick way to go from a sub-url, like [a non-default tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles?tab=questions) to the primary user page, to share a URL, say, or just quickly get back to the default view without remembering what tabs that is.

Comment: @Oded btw now avatar is not vertically aligned with the name.

Comment: Yes, that's been reported already.

Comment: @Oded why the fact that the avatar became bigger is the reason to decline it...

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The avatar preview when editing profile is too small; enlarge this preview please to the size it was earlier?

> [image]

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - the suggested design is much too busy. We did try to design something like this in early on, but decided against it.

The "Badges" should contain all the badges information you show -- the 'next tag badge' in the "Reputation" section to its left should be in here --- and you could show much more information.

If it's something I'm going to look at regularly, I would soon be wanting to see much more of the information I could be getting (and care about). I suggest something more like:

[image]

... thus showing the next tag badge info in the "badges" section, the newest of each badge color (though the most recent 2 badges would be a decent alternative), and the mouseover text replaces the redundant color information with how many of those badges are tag badges.

This is quite deliberately busier, since the "clean" look -- while it is nice for locating the information the first time you look at it, quickly becomes "bare" looking as you get used to it.

That will free up space in the 'reputation' section for other data (I suggest weekly/monthly/quarterly reputation, but there are other fine choices)

Comment: While I like the idea of showing more information, I feel like the lack of padding here makes it feel more cluttered. You can also find this information on the "Badges" tab as well as the "Profile" page.

Comment: That "the information can be found elsewhere" is true of essentially all the proposed new displays.

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - for performance reasons we will not be doing this.

I would like a link to a users chat profile for that specific site.

This will show the chat rooms he/she is in and you will be able to invite a user to a private chat room.

Comment: Where would that go to?

Comment: To a private chat with the user. Now it comes up after heaps of comments somehow.

Comment: That is not a private chat with a user, it is a question or answer related chat. I don't think they want to encourage 1 to 1 chats to much.

Comment: I agree but it seems that sometimes people just comment to then have the possibility to chat. So I think it would make sense when people which just interacted would have the possiblity to chat then.

Comment: How about a link to the user's chat profile only. You can invite them to a room from there.

Comment: I like that better.

Comment: @Thomas: If you agree on the above from Jan, please edit your answer. I will be happy to upvote then.

Comment: Done, I like that idea also. I think it will be helpful and speed up the answer process sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

In IE11 (yes, I know) the icon on Privileges to show that you're about to follow an external link (?) is chopped off at the bottom. In Chrome this icon is complete.

[image: privileges icon chopped]

Minor thingy... and I just checked: I'm not zoomed in/out.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Firefox

Comment: @PythonMaster Why are you adding tags to people's answers? Especially [meta-tag:status-completed] which is a moderator tag.

Answer (score 8):

Two points about the next-badge window:

- The default for me was Autobiographer, so I thought the little pencil icon next to it was to edit my profile to get the badge, rather than to choose the next badge to track. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- I can select Illuminator (gold) as the next badge to track even though I haven't even earned Explainer (bronze).  The current badge progress bars shown in the review queues only show the next tiered badge.  The next-badge selection should only show me the lowest tier I haven't yet earned, rather than just listing all possible badges. [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we don't see a good reason to disallow tracking any badges. You are the one in the driver seat here, after all.

Comment: "The next-badge selection should only show me the lowest tier I haven't yet earned, rather than just listing all possible badges"? Yes.

Answer (score 8):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - Having an edit icon suggests to people that this is something that can be changed. Removing it means that's not longer the case and the feature would become much less discoverable.

I feel the 'Select your next badge' functionality should be accessed from a single-click on the progress bar, and the badge information (currently single-click) should be mouseover text like on the Recently Earned badge.

<strike>This would also mean that the 'Edit' Icon can disappear entirely, meaning we wouldn't have two of the same icon for two different things within 50 pixels of each other:</strike> The 'posts edited' icon has now been changed

[image: Badges and Impact boxes]

I would suggest:

- Remove the 'Edit Next Badge' button entirely
- Make clicking on the progress take you to the 'Select your Next badge' screen.
- Remove the current 'single click' popup entirely

  - We already have the X/X badge progress above the progress bar
  - Make the tooltip/mouseover text the badge description

[image: Click progress box]

Comment: Agree!! Because everything else is now some sort of mouseover, even though I know I have to click to see badge description, I always find myself mousing over the progress bar and subsequently being annoyed by the fact that it doesn't show the badge description. It also looks like a button and I get disappointed every time I click and what amounts to an elaborate tooltip is all I get. It seems visually designed to work the way Robotnik suggests, but then it doesn't. That's annoying!

Comment: @Oded - Ok, keep the icon, My main beef with it was that it was the same as the one across from it at the time. But what of the rest? Removing the "How to earn dialog", filling in the tooltip instead etc?

Comment: We've discussed those as well, but will not be changing them. We are looking at making the information for badges like curious better.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - turns out there was a profile image handling change yesterday, unrelated to the changes for the Activity page, which broke the page for users who uploaded a profile picture.

When trying to save the changes in the new `Edit Profile & Settings` tab I got the error `Invalid image type`. I only added a link to my GitHub profile before clicking the save profile button.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Just to confirm - you did not change your image at all?

Comment: @Oded I only changed my profile picture once (around 3 months ago). I did not change it when I got this error.

Comment: @Oded Reproduced by editing "about me" and nothing else. The image was there for almost a month. Note: I got this error when editing profile on another site, not on Meta.

Comment: @Oded I added a small problem with a stretched profile picture to this answer, it could be related. As FamousBlueRaincoat reported, the same error shows up when trying to edit my Stack Overflow profile.

Comment: I found [a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250044/241622) for my second problem so I will edit it out of here.

Comment: [Another report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250179/259867), specifically mentioning the file type is PNG. I also use PNG for the image.

Comment: Sorry, delete my answer to avoid duplicated. Yes, I had the same issue too. Currently avatar is PNG and was not changed at all when trying to edit my profile

Comment: I just found a separate meta post about this [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286854/1928529).

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The impact box, seems to be missing a space between the number of flags and the words "helpful flags". Also, given the example has the same order of magnitude for helpful flags and votes cast, shouldn't the digits line up.

Screenshot is from Mac running Firefox 36.

[image: Helpful flags]

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - with you in the next build

Per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249993) request the color of accept background is the new light green. But accepts now look *very* ill:

> [image]

Please *leave everything consistent*, as in the request I mentioned, but change new light green to **old good dark green**, which is still used, for example, on SO:

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

> Or see if my age has changed. (Actually, the last one feels may feel like a waste most days, but ~0.3% of the time, it reminds me it's my birthday - YAY!)

Not to be the bearer of bad news, but I fear you may forget your birthday with the new profile version, as age seems to have been removed.

Was the removal intentional? I don't want to forget *my* birthday now too.

Comment: Yup I'm 99.7% sure it was intentional, and personally I agree with it. Age caused more grief than good, e.g. people attacking mods for being "too young". Official stamp would be welcome though. :)

Comment: That said, they should also remove the Birthday field from profile editing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Well great, now who is going to remember my birthday?! To be honest though, I don't usually look at age much because it doesn't really matter as long as they are not violating ToS (i.e. a listed age under the official limit). Good point about the excessive field.

Comment: Actually, age is interesting sometimes. [Doorknob](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/18167/9109) comes to my mind.

Comment: @Palec That's not a valid reason to have it. Besides, it can be moved to one's about me.

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Hovering over the (selected) badge progress on the main profile page darkens the badge colour and reveals the actual badge:

[image]

Now click on edit and hover over any of the listed badges' progress bar. No badge is displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There are some *strange* things going on with the mobile site (I'm using Safari on an iPhone 4).

Reputation graph display issues:

[image: screenshot iPhone weird rep display]

Badge color confusion:

[image: screenshot iPhone weird badges]

Obsidian badges?

[image: more iPhone weird badges]

Comment: I think they are working on a mobile site stripped version.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250114/259214

Comment: We've updated the mobile versions of these pages - is this still an issue (BTW - it would help if you mention browser/OS/device & versions)

Answer (score 7):

Not a big deal, but this doesn't seem quite good for users those care symmetry more than usual (at least for me).

In Activity and Edit Profile&Settings tab, Network Profile position is not in the same line with the object next to it (username).

[image: Network Profile position]

In `profile.css`, reducing `top` from 9px to 6px for `.additional-links` makes it better (however, I don't know if that class is used in any other elements).

Comment: We recently changed the profile image size - we will be getting the links lined up too, no worries.

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the page which lists my flags, helpful spam flags don't have a space between "spam" and "helpful" words (or, more apparently, "spam" has a too big `padding-right`)

> [image]

Comment: Yikes! Good catch... margin of 0 on `.bounty-fix` class is causing this.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with the new profile pages. No idea why you though this was a good place to post it.

Comment: @Oded I am very sorry, just saw this bug on MSE in the flag history and decided to report there, because ui seems to be new and, after all, it is profile page.

Comment: It is a sub page, linked to from the profile page. It wasn't something we changed at all for this project (the link has more visibility than the old profile page that's all - possibly why you thought it is new). Might have changed with the CSS updates that many sites have been getting, unrelated to the profile page.

Answer (score 7):

The number of questions per tag is not vertically centered, and is out-of-line against the `x`:

[image]

This is because `.item-multiplier-count` was given `font-size: 10px;` while `.item-multiplier-x` suffers from the inherited `font-size` of 13px. If the `font-size: 10px;` is unchecked:

[image]

Please make things line up. :)

Comment: +1, this is critical bug.

Comment: Duplicate of [a report by nhahtdh](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250445/238706), but better described.

Answer (score 6):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I would really like to decrease the information distance on the other tabs, especially on Answers and Questions it would be useful. Please make the shiny (almost empty) top grey boxes appear only in the summary, so that I actually see my posts when I change the tab (currently, I have to change the tab and scroll, but most often I need to click one of the two or three posts, and the scroll could be therefore avoided).

> [image]

Comment: I disagree pretty strongly – if you hide the top boxes, then the tab navigation moves around. I *never* want the same set of navigation to move around on the page. (Besides that, they'd move to tabs directly under tabs and would probably look really ugly. :) )

Comment: @Laura Why would it float? You simply place it above the grey boxes. Also, the space from the tab title to the red line could be reduced.

Answer (score 6):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - this will be different on each site.

Please, for the sake of my eyes - can you do something about the border colors for the boxes. On my monitor they are barely visible and a huge distraction. Perhaps some more contrast?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (though we can't repro the webkit issue you have - seems to be an issue with your fonts there)

Good work! I like it. One small thing I noticed:

The height of the "Impact" box is slightly higher than the other 2 boxes:

[image]

The top one is Firefox, the bottom one my WebKit-based browser; here the problem is exagerated due to the "~215 people reached" being broken.

This is not just me, I've seen this in the screenshots of a few other answers as well; and on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250044/166789) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250044/166789) one it even seems slightly smaller...

Comment: Could you tell me what's your browser and OS?

Comment: @StéphaneMartin I use Linux; the top screenshot is Firefox 35.0.1, the top one is dwb, which is a fairly obscure webkit based-browser (which I don't really expect you to support, which I also added the Firefox screenshot).

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - we changed the size to 48*48, which imgur supports, so the full, original, image will not download, but the cropped one will.

On the Activity tab, when I right-click on my avatar next to my name on the upper right and select "View Image", it loads a huge 1453x1453 version of that image (presumably the exact image that I uploaded for my avatar).

[image]

That means the Activity tab is loading the huge image and shrinking it in the upper right.  I think it should load an image that has already been shrunk on the server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure gravatar.com has already done the image shrinking, and the page loading is being done through that magic.

Comment: @hardmath When I right-click and do a "View Image" on my avatar in other places, it loads the same size avatar, never the full-size version.

Comment: When I do inspect element on that image, it goes to `<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3398257417092655df73d9a8912f2832?s=36&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" width="36" height="36">`

Comment: @hardmath That's weird, mine doesn't go to gravatar - it loads the full size image from i.stack.imgur.com.

Comment: We have two options for avatars - you can either use gravatar, or you can upload your own (which goes to our private imgur instance). That's why you're seeing two different behaviors...you and @hardmath are using two different services.

Answer (score 6):

In ["my logins"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current), there should be more space between "change password" and "remove":

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Well, thank you :-) But congratulations for what? My birthday? Drinking a beer? Finally getting around to doing the dishes?

It seems the text is somehow 'behind' the grey box...

Going to the web inspector and removing a few characters seems to fix it:

[image]

This is Firefox 36.0.1 on Linux, but also observed in WebKit.

Answer (score 5):

When I click "Go get it" on "Research Assistant",

[image]

it takes me to... preferences > interesting tags (https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current#interesting-tags).

Shouldn't it just link to the list of tags? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags)

Comment: I think the intent of this is to bring you to tags on which you have some knowledge.

Comment: @Mooseman is correct. To be clear, we expect a lot of these "Go Get Its" to get tweaked based on feedback, but in this case, we were aiming at tags you have actively expressed interest or expertise in.

Comment: @Jaydles There might still be a bug here...I see that there's an anchor tag in that URL, but my page doesn't jump to it. It's kind of confusing to load the page and see a big "preferences" header rather than the tags.

Comment: Also, I am kind of surprised to learn we don't have a "mine" tab on the /tags page! We usually tab all the things!

Comment: @Laura That's a great idea — please do that!

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On the applications tab of settings, when I remove an application it looks like the request is AJAX'd in and the page jumps to the top. Could we make the page stay in the same place?

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - this isn't selectable. As commented, the interval used is the one with the highest score.

I'm listed somewhere in the top 7% this *quarter*:

[image]

There's no indication on how to change this to "this week", "this year" or "overall".

Comment: There isn't. It is auto generated, I think it shows your best score.

Comment: Yes, it is best score. It is the same on the old page.

Comment: @Tim: It's far less invasive on the older profile page, so less of a "What's going on here? How can I change it?" feeling.

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - the design doesn't lend itself for another statistic, we also have a lot of different review queues. So, just showing a number here is not meaningful.

In that impact box (listing edits, helpful flags and votes), could we also include 'reviews completed'?  I think this is an important counting statistic and would let users who keep working the queues even after getting those gold badges show off their dedication.  (The top-20-all-time list in each queue a) only shows 20 users and b) isn't shown in the profile.)

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - The badges that were chosen for badge progress were selected with a few different constraints in place - one was for badges that we believe going after is a net benefit to the site. Another one was impact on performance / feasibility of progress tracking implementation. As result, some badges are not trackable at this time.

I love this new possibility to view badge progress.

Any plans to add to those stats "Tenacious" and "Unsung Hero"?

And also "Generalist" and "Pundit".

Comment: The point of the progress bars is to encourage you to go take whatever action gets the badge.  For the "consolation badges", it's not clear what action to take.  Do you set out to write acceptable-but-not-upvote-worthy answers?  (I still support showing progress, but the call to action is just weird.)

Comment: Also (favorite|stellar|nice|good|great|popular|notable|famous) question, enlightened, generalist, guru, (nice|good|great) answer, populist, reversal, commentator, pundit, … and others. There are many badges that are not available as goals. I would especially love to see the generalist. But I assume these depend too much on the behavior of others. And generalist can even lose progress as the overall interests of the community shift and top tags change.

Comment: @Palec Yes, that would be great, but note that all the current trackable badges can only be earned once and not per-post. What post should be tracked with per-post badges? And commentator, pundit and generalist are great to be tracked. Do you allow me to add them to my request?

Comment: Of course you can add them, @nicael.

Comment: The badges that were chosen for badge progress were selected with a few different constraints in place - one was for badges that we believe going after is a net benefit to the site. Another one was impact on performance / feasibility of progress tracking implementation. As result, some badges are not trackable at this time.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: If the sole purpose was *encouragement*, I don't see the point of listing the [Disciplined badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/disciplined). It's odd to provide an incentive to delete a post with a score of 3 or more.

Comment: @Werner See [What is the purpose of the "disciplined" badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7609/262399).

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - with you in the next build.

My top tag is required tag, but it renders as usual (should have grey background, but has blue):

> [image]

Also happens if the top tag is some mod-only red tag.

Comment: We appreciate the attempt to leave so much feedback, but it's hard for us to read it unless you can make it bigger, and possibly use a more robust color? Thanks!  :P

Comment: @Jay wait, bigger. You mean zoom in a bit? ;) OK, I have a small reserve to use. and wats wrong with color... Shouldn't freehand be red?

Comment: @Jay I dezoomed the images.

Comment: I had no idea what you were talking about here until you mentioned the mod-only tags.

Comment: @Kev http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags, "legend" in the bottom :)

Comment: I was going to say "Top tag" should be "Top non-required tag" since it's unlikely on meta to have a non-required tag as your top tag.

Comment: @Mooseman This happens often to devs - ones have [status-completed], other have [careers] :)

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - if we do display hidden communities, this would be confusing (hey, why is it there - I just hid it!), as well as be inconsistent. The profile page should look the same to you as it does to others. The hidden communities are one click away.

If I hide my communities, can they not be hidden *for me*? It can be just applied the same background which is applied to deleted answers.

Also, an ability to (un)hide directly from the accounts section is great.

Like in this snippet:

```js
$(".hide").click(function(){if($(this).text()!="unhide"){$(this).text("unhide");$(this).addClass("deleted-post");$(this).parent().parent().addClass("deleted-answer");}else{$(this).text("hide");$(this).removeClass("deleted-post");$(this).parent().parent().removeClass("deleted-answer");}})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/all.css?v=1489ba291cc6"></head><body style="height:100%;overflow:hidden"><div id="content" class="snippet-hidden"><div id="mainbar-full" class="user-show-new"><div><div id="user-panel-accounts" class="user-panel user-panel-left"><div class="user-panel-content"><table class="user-accounts lines" style="text-align:left"><tbody><tr><td class="icon-cell"><div class="favicon favicon favicon-lifehacks" title="Lifehacks Stack Exchange"></div></td><td><a  href="http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/21/" >Lifehacks </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="hide">hide</span></td><td class="reputation"><span class="reputation-score">2,159</span> rep</td><td class="badges"><span title="6 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">6</span></span><span title="25 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">25</span></span></td></tr><tr><td class="icon-cell"><div class="favicon favicon favicon-stackoverflow" title="Stack Overflow"></div></td><td><a  href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/">Stack Overflow </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="hide">hide</span></td><td class="reputation"><span class="reputation-score">1,776</span> rep</td><td class="badges"><span title="4 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">4</span></span><span title="8 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">8</span></span><span title="43 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">43</span></span></td></tr><tr><td class="icon-cell"><div class="favicon favicon favicon-stackexchangemeta" title="Meta Stack Exchange"></div></td><td><a  href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/">Meta Stack Exchange </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="hide">hide</span></td><td class="reputation"><span class="reputation-score">1,653</span> rep</td><td class="badges"><span title="3 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">3</span></span><span title="29 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">29</span></span><span title="82 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">82</span></span></td></tr><tr><td class="icon-cell"><div class="favicon favicon favicon-craftcms" title="Craft CMS Stack Exchange"></div></td><td><a  href="http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/250/">Craft CMS </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="hide">hide</span></td><td class="reputation"><span class="reputation-score">1,055</span> rep</td><td class="badges"><span title="4 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">4</span></span><span title="26 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">26</span></span></td></tr><tr><td class="icon-cell"><div class="favicon favicon favicon-emacs" title="Emacs Stack Exchange"></div></td><td><a  href="http://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/7/">Emacs </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="hide">hide</span></td><td class="reputation"><span class="reputation-score">866</span> rep</td><td class="badges"><span title="1 gold badge"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">1</span></span><span title="6 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">6</span></span><span title="18 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">18</span></span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 5):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - it is difficult to find a good place for this stat on the activity page, given the new design.

**I miss the *last seen* item on the Activity page when pursuing the Fanatic badge**, even when Fanatic badge is selected. Now it is on the Profile page only. I’d like to be able to tell if I have to do an action today, or if I have already done. I have some of my Stack Exchange profile pages in pinned tabs in my Firefox and the *last seen* field used to remind me to show some activity.

Answer (score 5):

Tag scores *definitely* need some padding;

> [image]

I'd suggest the same new border which is currently around rep changes and answer scores:

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The tooltips on the `posts edited` and `votes cast` are only on the number. Can they be expended, so they cover the text itself too, just like `helpful flags`?

[image: no tooltip on text here]

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-regression](/questions/tagged/status-regression)

This was [reported and marked as completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249994) but the problem is (still? again?) here today:

Clicking on *Track the next one* after earning a badge fails:

[image: *Track the next one* gives a *Unable to load popup* error message; handdrawn circles and arrows]

The console tells me:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> ```
> jquery.min.js:4 GET https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/activity/badge-card/next-badge-popup?userId=140890&isTagBadge=false&_=1425297184972 404 (Not Found)
> ```

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Hiding communities doesn't hide network posts and result is quite weird:

> [image]

Comment: The list of [communities I personally see](https://i.imgur.com/I8z0Qis.png) includes CodeGolf.SE (and Vi.SE), but I can confirm what you are seeing when I open it up without being logged in.

Comment: @Kev Of course I know. You just used the new feature to hide communities and I am reporting that it doesn't hide network posts.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I hide sites, posts from that site are also hidden.

Comment: @Oded Any idea why I have a different set of communities shown when I'm logged in compared to them I'm logged out? I think that's the key to the issue here.

Comment: @Oded can you repro it with [Kevin](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/159034/kevin-brown)?

Comment: No, I can't. From what I can tell, the posts in the list are for sites that are not hidden, also for @Kevin.

Comment: @Kevin - IIRC (not in front of code right now), we cache the page for anonymous users, so it can very well be different depending on when the cache last expired.

Comment: @Oded [thats what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vWdZH.png)

Comment: @nicael - that looks like the anonymous view (I see that when viewing the profile in incognito), but not when viewing directly. Could be a bad if statement somewhere to do with mod/employee powers (alternatively, a bad if statement to do with anonymous users). Gives me something to chase tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Oded I noticed this was [meta-tag:status-completed], but now I've got _the exact opposite issue_ with the same symptoms: [I've lost all of my network posts](https://i.imgur.com/EDku4vx.png) and the [communities still don't line up](https://i.imgur.com/lSJfokb.png). Did I flip some "privacy" switch and forget about it?

Comment: @KevinBrown - by design. On a site which you have hidden, we pretend you have no network posts or other sites (we show you the other communities, but only to yourself/mods). To fix... unhide the current site ;)

Comment: @Oded The problem is that [I didn't hide those communities](https://i.imgur.com/7robyd9.png)... I think? [Meta.SE should actually be hidden.](https://i.imgur.com/QCacf1S.png) Perhaps I'm completely missing something, but even after hiding and making them visible again there doesn't appear to be a change.

Comment: @KevinBrown - but you did hide **this** community. When hiding the community you are on, we pretend you don't have _anything else_ on the network.

Comment: TBH, we are still figuring this piece out, in terms of how it should display (or not) to yourself, moderators and others.

Comment: @Oded Ah, that makes much more sense. Wasn't completely obvious at first. :)

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On Chromium 40.0.2214.111 (Developer Build) Ubuntu 14.04:

[image: Screenshot]

On the Edit Profile & Settings page, the icon overlaps with the text.

This also happens on Firefox 36.0, also Ubuntu 14.04. Though I can see in screenshots from other answers that this does not happen to everyone.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - though this answer now qualifies on this post for other reasons (having score of 5 or more)

P.S. I call BS on the "Impact" algorithm.

Before I posted this answer, my "Impact" was in the hundreds. Let's take a look at it's value now, half an hour after posting this answer:

[image: Screenshot]

And guess how many views this question has:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hmm. This answer shouldn't get you the views for this question; there are too many "above" it.  Thanks - we'll investigate.

Comment: @Jaydles Happened to me too.  Yesterday I was [at 10k](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250685/160551), after posting that answer, I jumped to 31k reached today.

Comment: Can you confirm the first issue is fixed for you? Still looking at the impact algorithm.

Comment: @Oded First issue fixed. :)

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Badges are misaligned in a few places on the mobile web UI (iOS 8.1.3 on iPhone 6):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1, don't get a downvote on it...

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The info pane when clicking on your next badge goes off-screen on the mobile web UI (iOS 8.1.3 on iPhone 6):

[image]

Comment: We removed most such popups from the mobile view.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Something is up with the votes spacing.  It looks fine when I view my own profile:
[image: Image with appropriate spacing before "votes cast" text]

But when I look at other people's profiles, the space before "votes cast" is missing.

Here's [Jaydles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles?tab=activity):

[image: Image with no spacing between votes and label text]

And to show the number of digits don't appear to matter, here's [nicael](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=activity):

[image: Another image with no spacing between votes and label text]

And here's [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/188189/robert-longson?tab=activity):

[image: Another image with no spacing between votes and label text]

These screenshots were taken on IE 11 on Windows 8.1, but I can also reproduce the behavior on Firefox and Safari (OS X).  If I switch to private browsing, I also see the lack of a space on my own profile.

Answer (score 5):

The ranking text size is a little too small for some people to read. If you are not paying attention, you might miss the ranking text. If possible, can the size of that text be enlarged so it can be clearly be seen but not too big? Here's the screenshot:
[image]

And here's the screenshot for Meta.SE:
[image]

Please make that text bigger!

Comment: For completeness you should post the view on [meta.se] (since it's the only site currently showing the updated activity page)... [so] doesn't have it yet.

Comment: Your email address is visible in the top image - might want to fix that.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) We moved the position of the tooltip.

If my mouse trajectory towards "posts edited", "helpful flags", "votes cast" goes through "people reached", a tooltip, which appears very helpfully to explain what is "people reached", effectively blocks my way towards those links I mentioned.

E.g. I was going to "helpful flags" link...

> [image]

And... whoops! I didn't expect this popup...

> [image]

Can it have some delay plz? So the popup shows when I *stop* my cursor, not just pass this trigger. Don't make me make unnecessary laps around the link I need :D

Comment: The delay on the chart tooltip was already declined.

Comment: @Moose Looks like after 27 answers, I finally posted a dupe :D But let them reweigh this suggestion, maybe they'll do now :)

Comment: @Stéphane Thanks :) When will the fix be rolled out?

Answer (score 5):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Newest badge ≠ next badge, or does it?

[This user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284141/michaelpri) got "Suffrage" [16h ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/118/suffrage?userid=284141), so it can't be just caching? Anyway, looks pretty weird..

> [image]

**Edit:** I understood why this happens. Once a user wins a badge, he can choose another one to track. But until he choose, next badge is his last earned badge. So I propose not to show "Next badge" if a user has already won it but hasn't chosen a new one to track yet.

Answer (score 5):

In the profile page, please don't put the username *inside* the 'about me' box. As it is, when you scroll down in that box, you can't see the user's name any longer. I see no reason for that.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - with you in the next build.

If I hide one of the communities, the count does not change.

[image: Ooh look I'm hiding something]

That's not such a problem if I'm logged in but it's still like that if I'm logged out so anyone can tell I'm trying to hide something. If I want to make something private it should be private, no clues allowed.

Answer (score 4):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Can we lower the reputation graph a little so there is the white space like in the other groups? The graph now seems to 'break' the space from the header.

[image]

Comment: Disagree. It is more important to keep the `height` of each box identical.

Comment: Then make them all a little higher, or change the layout so it doesn't break.

Comment: Can we shrink the huge boxes? I could sleep in them now, how large they are.

Comment: There is a *lot* of empty space, I guess they are going for the "clean look".

Comment: The space isn't my problem. I have a large screen. The gaps is my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I get used to thicker borders of tag scores, can you please bring back the thick tag scores? Those borders are just too thin:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

My next privilege is the "Edit questions and answers", and when I click on the progress bar, there is an extra ")" at the end of the text.

> Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Duplicate of this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250005/179419, it's there for all the privileges apparently, you can see it in a few more screenshots as well.

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - this is not an improvement in readability.

This seems like it might be breaking some contrast check standard:

[image: progbar1]

Doubly so when hovered:

[image: progbar2]

Triply so when only half-full:

[image: progbar3]

Possible fix?

[image: progbar4]

Seems a bit "Windows 95-ish" though. Maybe having the label *on* the progress bar - which already contrasts highly with its own background - isn't the best idea.

Comment: The "possible fix" looks cool, but I'm not sure it is as easy implementable as one might think. As far as I know, the webdevs should duplicate the text `Established user` and then with some JS goofiness calculate how far the bar has filled and *then* add some clipping to the upper layer of text. Seems a lot of work for something as simple as that. Apart from the practical side, I don't think it is better readable than the current design. The brain *expects* a single word to be same-coloured. (Damn racist.) A lighter green with a darker brown/black should do just fine.

Comment: I must respectfully disagree with the decline reason @Oded - [It's not that hard](http://jsfiddle.net/xy4tr6ab/)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's a smart solution but I'd still not do it because I find the text hard to read when you have 2 very different color next to each other.

Comment: I do agree though, I don't find this better readable at all, and I've never liked superfluous markup for something as trivial as this.

Comment: (It can be done with no duplicate HTML markup, but as expected this is not cross-browser friendly: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/xy4tr6ab/2/)

Comment: @StéphaneMartin I'm inclined to agree with you - I touched lightly on that in the last line of my post, I just wanted to point out that "non-trivial" seemed like the wrong rejection reason ;)

Comment: Smart approach. Didn't think about that...

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - We struggled with the layouts here for a long while. For many people, vertically aligning top network posts with top posts would cause an overly large amount of whitespace. We needed to consider many use cases, and settled on what you see.

The big wall of blue text hits me in the face ....

Also,

[image: make these two equal]

Align these two columns, for a calmer look (which means either pushing Top Posts down or removing one of the network profiles:

[image]

Comment: We struggled with the layouts here for a long while. For many people, vertically aligning top network posts with top posts would cause an overly large amount of whitespace. We needed to consider many use cases, and settled on what you see.

Answer (score 4):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - as others have said in comments, the icons have been updated, most screenshots are from before that.

Why are there 2 different sets of icons for the IMPACT box?  I see the following set of icons:

[image]

My "posts edited" has a paragraph icon, my "helpful flags" has a flag completely attached to the flagpole, and my "votes cast" has an up arrow that has a stem.  At least [one other person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250237/202205) in this thread has those icons.

But most people in this thread who've posted screenshots have a different set of icons:

[image]

That shows a pencil for the "posts edited", a flag with space between it and the flagpole for the "helpful flags", and an up arrow without a stem for the "votes cast".

Comment: Apparently, they changed the icons. Most of the screenshots here were posted before the change.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Interesting.  I think the pencil icon makes a lot more sense than the paragraph icon for "posts edited".

Comment: Maybe, but in other places they use the same pencil icon for "click here to edit", so I can see how this could be confusing.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Oh really? I've only seen a similar pencil icon next to comments that have been edited.

Comment: In the same new profile,  there is this editing icon near _next badge_.

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - please post this as a new feature-request. This is one of the parts that were not changed as part of the profile page redesign (barring a small number of style changes). We are asking for feedback specific to what did change.

Profile tab already shows my badges for top tags:

> [image]

Can this also be implemented for the tags in the ["activity > summary"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=summary) and ["activity > tags"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=tags) please?

> [image]

Comment: Declining this as it isn't about items that changed, but a request to change something that's been that way since before the redesign.

Answer (score 4):

Would you please increase the font size of question count by tag (and badge count) by 1 or 2 points? It's very straining on the eyes to read the numbers.

I have included an older design from Anime & Manga for comparison.

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - declining this as it isn't feedback on the changes to the profile page. This can (and should) be posted as a separate [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), given that it has nothing to do with the announced changes to the profile page.

It would be nice to see how many +1's your activities received in the [`activity->activities`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/187614/bram-vanroy?tab=activity) tab. Additionally this can be expanded over most of the tabs on that page, e.g. accepts, posts, comments. Yes, comments as well. As it is now, there is no way to see if your comments are appreciated in any way other than visiting the posts in detail.

It should be worked out in more detail, but for instance in the 'posts' tab, when a post is 'asked', the details of that post can be visible. I am aware that this is already visible in the other view of `questions`, so this is not my main concern. The upvotes for comments, however, seems like a nice addition.

Comment: You are giving feedback on something that wasn't changed in the new profile (bar some style tweaks) - by all means, please post this as a new question - a feature request. We are trying to collect feedback here on things that have changed for the profile pages specifically.

Comment: @Oded [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250604/adding-more-info-up-downvotes-to-activity-feed).

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we are working on click consistency across all the top boxes. We do not intend to have every single element clickable.

The "Reputation" header, rep number, and new rep changes should link to the [rep page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation), while the graph should link to its [Father Graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/3548243/nicael?tab=reputation) in the network profile.

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is a mouse-over tooltip for the reputation gained on the top tag which seems superfluous:

[image]

Comment: Superfluous for small numbers, sure, but when the number is large and is abbreviated as _9.8k_, the tooltip will show the exact value.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: The representation of the number matches that of "what happened since you last clicked on the reputation tab". How long would have to wait to view a 9.8k reputation change in some specific tag?! I doubt that number would represent "total reputation in that tag".

Comment: For you and for me and for most mortals, perhaps not. For some, though, who gather reputation points by the boat load, being a way for a day or two _might_ result in a reputation total on a tag >1000.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - No more 0/0 bar now

I assume 0/0 below refers to the second requirement of the [Socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic). However, I'm not sure how "maintained a positive record" implies 0/0:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the [community-hider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current), this phrase:

> New sites that you join will be linked to your other communities by default.

might confuse users. It seems that by "other" you mean "visible", could it be stated more clearly (replacing "other" with "visible")?

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - with you in the next build. I had to read this a few times to get what you meant.

If I win a badge, the tag badge window shouldn't say "Track the next one" if I don't have all the privileges yet. But in this case privileges are tracked, not tag badges.

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - as the basic requested functionality already exists.

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - as it isn't exactly as requested here.

I want to be able to track my progress toward an arbitrary tag badge.

If I click the 'choose which badge to track' button, it lists all the built-in badges, but there are no tag badges.  If I type 'discussion' in the search box, for example, there's no results.

It would be nice if as you typed, it showed built-in badges and tag badges that match the search.  I don't think it's a good idea to try and find a way to fit all the many tags I could be working towards in the non-search lists, but if I'm searching, I want to see everything including the tag badges.

### TL;DR:

Please add the tag badges to the 'choose which badge to track' search results when you are doing a search.  Don't include the tag badges in the default list of Available badges when that popup opens, only include the tag badges when you do a search, and sort them so they come after the built-in badges.

Comment: The ability to track tag badges comes in after all privileges were earned - at that point, the place where privilege tracking was shown will have tag badges (and allow for selecting which one to track)

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I looked through the other answer and I *don't think* this has been reported yet. I just earned my bronze badge in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) because of the rather excellent prompt. So I'm ready for my next tag badge:

[image: Sad panda]

I know I can manually select the next tag badge to pursue, but wouldn't it be better if that were done for me automatically? In addition, the progress bar shows I have 19/20, which bugged me ever since I posted my answer. But I figured it would be updated when the badge was actually awarded. I understand it could be a performance problem to update everyone's profile every time the do an action that might change one of these displays since that's basically all actions. But it would be nice if the display was updated when the badge was awarded.

Comment: pretty sure this is a caching issue.  I think we've *just* gotten the "next [non-tag] badge to update in real-time on pageload, but Jarrod's still working on a more live refresh for the tag badge.  I think that'll fix your issue.

Comment: @Jaydles: Nope, I'm still stuck at [19/20 answers on shell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1438/jon-ericson?tab=badges). The congratulations is pretty nice on my Curious badge, however. ;-)

Comment: I pushed a fix for this last night; is it still an issue?

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) needs to be reviewed and updated to match the new layout.

For instance the image in [How do I delete my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) does not reflect the new shinyness. I.e.

[image: How do I delete my account]

needs updating.

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - this box would obscure something wherever it is located, and we feel need to remain contained inside the badge box it is relating to.

The current badge *recommendation* overlays with the badge progress (top-right):

[image]

Perhaps moving this into the bottom-right corner will provide the least likely opportunity to overlay with anything. Alternatively, consider making adding this to the *outside* top-left so it seems like a "file folder tag":

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we cannot "demo" this on all sites at this time. There is a lot of backend work on our .less files to make them consistent (and allow us to push features like these pages across the network faster).

From reading the description given it seems like a great idea; by quantizing your contributions it really helps to motivate you to contribute further. However, I would suggest providing the demo of the new version to all accounts in the stack exchange community, as I am currently unable to really test it out because I have made absolutely no contributions to Meta Stack Exchange, so the interface for me is pretty much 3 grey boxes.

Comment: MSE is the playground for this kind of stuff, so if you like it: participate!

Comment: Eh, you can look at others' profiles though, since they do have proper randomized statistics. Demos for beta profiles seems a lot of work to be short-lived.

Answer (score 3):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Here is the display I got from my profile, it seems buggy comparing to the other screenshots I've seen of other users of the new privilege feature:

[image: privilege]

Same thing for the badge notification:

[image: badge]

I'm on Arch with Chrome v42.

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we don't like to steal focus - this is something that should be decided by the user.

When I want to select a badge to pursue, the form does not get focused. Hitting tab does not help – it jumps between links on the profile page and does not get (within a few hits) to the search box. I’d expect the **badge search input field to get focused** immediately after the badge selection form pops up.

Comment: Is it possible to at least give the textbox a reasonable tabindex?

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can we have a separator in the tooltip here too, just like in the actual text?

[image]

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: Agreed, but they tend to do it nowadays. (take a look at the `10,000 rep` behind the tooltip. That should be consistent in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - this is much too small of a hit target and would be totally unrecoverable.

In the "profile" tab, after my top tags, those badge icons link to the corresponding tag badges. Please implement there, in the "activity" tab, similar functionality.

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

There something wrong in the updates of the badge progress information:

[image]

Not sure whether it's due to caching... Also not sure whether this is specific to [Electorate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/electorate), but the secondary requirement needs some help.

Comment: Yes, badge progressions are currently updated once a day. We are looking at making them update more frequently.

Comment: @Oded: ...and fixing some of the secondary requirements.

Comment: Yes, we are actually taking a deeper look into that.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: "Web Presence" portion of editting profile]

Oh noes! The link, the stack overflow, and the kitty are hidden when you type something into the box!

<strike>Also there's no birdie or whatever Twitter's logo is.</strike>
I can see the birdie now, but the logos are still hidden.

Comment: [This has been mentioned already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250581/168244).

Comment: What browser? What OS? And what versions?

Comment: @Oded Firefox 38.0a2 (2015-02-28) on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @Oded The birdie is still missing :P

Comment: @JeffreyLin - we don't support browsers in alpha/beta. This kind of thing is just to be expected when using cutting edge.

Answer (score 3):

Consistency in the display of information associated with badge progress would be appreciated:

[Electorate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/electorate) (shows progress bar):

[image]

[Strunk & White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) (no progress bar):

[image]

[Marshal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal) (nothing):

[image]

Comment: We show progress bars (2 - not 1), when the badge requirements need two separate things to progress. Doing so when only one bar exists would completely duplicate the information on the bar you just clicked...

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

That's great you added new fancy tooltips (can be seen when hovering some stat in the "Impact box"). But the standard tooltips still appear, so they overlap the new ones (however my screenshot doesn't reflect it as it was taken from mobile).

> [image]

So I propose that the standard ones shouldn't be shown when the new ones work (which would happen if there is something wrong with loading javascript or you just disabled it).

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering "Where is the standard tooltips!? I don't see any..." on the screenshot, I believe it's not captured... but it's there.

Comment: @And yes, the screenshot is taken on mobile, while this problem exist on desktop :)

Comment: The excessive tooltips were removed. Should only have been used in a handful of places.

Comment: @Oded what about the second request...

Comment: Not sure I follow.

Comment: @Oded wait, seems that you removed the new tooltips?

Comment: Yes, the new style tooltips were supposed to go only in a small number of places... I went a bit overboard and then removed them from where they shouldn't have been.

Comment: @Oded Then everything okay :)

Comment: I don't believe you say that... what, no more bug reports?

Comment: @Oded I mean okay with *this* bug report.

Comment: I know... was just making a joke ;)

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

My reputation gained tooltip does not look nice:

[image]

Also, the title-text shows up too with the same text. Is there a way to stop it doing this as it's extra-messy having the same text rendered twice.

Chrome, Mac.

Comment: For the second point: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250715

Comment: @nicael [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/m9q3xqo5/) should sort that problem - removing/replacing the `title` attribute when the hover is triggered. That way the attribute is still accessible.

Answer (score 3):

The Top tags section looks pretty messy to me.

I presume these little coloured circles refer to some kind of badges, but something about the nesting and changing numbers of labels on each level is confusing to my eye.

I'd prefer a nested scrolly-table myself.

[image: Top Tags]

Answer (score 3):

On Samsung Galaxy S5 in Chrome, I am seeing that when I click to choose a badge to track, the background is not fully darkened, there is white space on the right.

> [image]

Comment: We'd expect one to use the mobile theme on a phone...

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Fixed, it will be live after our next production build.

The following applies to

- OS: Windows 8.1
- Browser: Chrome 41, IE 11, Firefox 34

For some reason, the labels on the y-axis of the reputation graph are out of alignment with the grey bars on my end.

[image: not-aligned]

Looking at a couple of images in this thread (especially those posted in March), it appears that I'm not the only one, though there are others without issues.

I mucked around and found out that using the CSS values

- `top: -3px` (originally -1px) in `.card.rep-card .graph-col .values`
- `margin-top: 3px` (originally 7px) in `.card.rep-card .graph-col .values li`

seems to fix the alignment on my end.

[image: fixed alignment]

Answer (score 3):

Number of days connected should be on the activity page. It changes every day, and I want to see it.

In fact, it's currently the main reason why I go to my profile page (I'm trying to get the Enthusiast badge). I know — I can set the next badge to Enthusiast. But still, I think this info should be on the Activity page. It's mostly useful to me, not to a random visitor to my profile. And if they're actually curious about this, they also probably are about the rest of my activity anyway.

Comment: You mean "visited X days, Y consecutive"? Only you see it, it's not displayed for other users viewing your profile.

Comment: Yes, this one. If only I can see it, then my request makes all the more sense. It should be on the Activity tab.

Comment: But it's not an activity, it's only a nice to have statistics, like the other stats in profile.

Comment: This is duplicate of [my report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250437/238706), which was considered [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: Well then I feel it is bad design. As per the description, the Profile is aimed at other users. What's the point of adding there a stat that only I can see? And Shadow I disagree, it is an activity to connect to the site. Otherwise why would there be a badge for it?

Answer (score 3):

Badges look strange on mobile (Nexus 5, Chrome, default settings)

[image]

Comment: Mobile is still semi-broken, and getting semi-fixed.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed now. /cc @Jaydles

Answer (score 3):

The 'Votes' button is on the next line:

[image]

I now no longer have '20' next to reputation, so it's "fixed".

Firefox 36.0.1 on Linux; also observed in WebKit.

Answer (score 3):

After clicking on 'choose what badge to track':

[image]

The content seems too large for the dialog? I'm also not sure about the location of the 'Search for a badge'-field? Shouldn't that be next to the buttons?

Firefox 36.0.1 on Linux; also observed in WebKit.

Answer (score 3):

Three-digit rep gains are misaligned in the mobile profile page and the upvotes are black (which was recently fixed for the desktop version of this profile page):

> [image]

Comment: Not only that, but the number overflows to the next line if it's a bit wider, e.g., 140: the last digit ends up on a new line. (Didn't take a screenshot when that happened, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - thanks for reporting. With you in the next build.

This seem minor, but inconsistent: `<rep> Rep.` would look better than `<rep> req.`, even if it is just to match up with the "tooltip":

[image]

The unit-of-measure is not "required", but "reputation".

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I get a **404 - Not found** when I click on posts edited in my profile.

[image]

The link points to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/133638/jehof?tab=activities&sort=revisions

Comment: `tab=activities` should redirect to `tab=allactions`. It was renamed.

Comment: This is already mentioned here: [Profile tab hyperlink should match name change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251683/168244)

Answer (score 3):

Really, who thought that the *number* of your recent names is clickable?

> [image]

Yes, I know that it was clickable also in the old design, but it's time to fix it.

1. Style it like link
2. Even better, make the whole phrase clickable

Answer (score 3):

The mini-reputation graph tooltip is showing decimals.

[image: mini-repuation graph]

Since reputation is always a whole number (and all of the numbers display `.00` anyway) it should only display whole numbers. This seems to be new behavior.

(Windows 7 Enterprise, Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112.16421))

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there are a few bugs to work out, but still leaves me wondering when you are going to roll this out to other sites on the network?

- Are you going to release a site (or sites) at a time, or one big roll out for all of StackLand?
- If you are going to roll out a couple of sites at a time, might I suggest a few

  - Anime and Manga
  - Code Review
  - Computer Science
  - Chemistry
  - Japanese
  - Cryptography
  - Blender
  - English Language Learners
  - Music

  Give us a little something to hold us over until we get our full-fledged site design, unless doing so will push us further back on the site graduation roll out

  ***NOTE:*** These are beta sites that have graduated but are waiting on site design and to have the new privilege levels turned on.
- What does the timeline look like for this change to spread over StackLand?

Comment: Not that I mean this as an implication about anything to do with you personally, but this list honestly looks like a list of favourite topics of a number of computer scientists I know. So I have to ask, why these sites? Why not SO, SU, DIY, Skeptics, Mi Yodea, or Physics? (Just to name a few examples) Why these sites?

Comment: These are beta sites that have graduated but are waiting on site design and to have the new privilege levels turned on.

Comment: We don't have a specific timeline for rolling this out. First, there are bugs and requests posted here that need to be fixed. Other than that, there is a bunch of backend work being done on our .less files for all the sites (to make them more consistent and allow new features to be promoted to all sites quickly) that is work-in-progress. We would like to roll it out to all sites in one go, but if that is too long in the future, we will have to select sites by .less readiness :(

Comment: Thank you for the response @Oded, I appreciate it.  I like the new look and feel and am very excited for it.  thank you guys for everything you do!

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - this will be different on each site.

Please add borders around the scores of accepted q&a, as it is done with the scores of non-accepted ones, for consistence and to make those scores of accepted answers not look visually smaller, at least for me, than the scores of non-accepted (because they have quite light background)

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - not everyone wants to click in order to get the information. Agreed this isn't giving *all* the information some of the time, but it is useful to have directly in front of people.

I would get rid of the information display next to the privilege and badge progress bars:

[image]

While they may relay the correct information in some instances - particularly when there is only a single requirement to satisfy, other instances will not be accurate in terms of this information. For example, as displayed above, the [Electorate gold badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/electorate) has a dual requirement in terms of the

1. *total number* of votes on *questions*; and
2. the *proportion* of votes on *questions*.

[Other question may have more complex requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168244). And in any these more complex cases, which one would be chosen to represent the visible requirement. Hence the suggestion to just get rid of it - free up the space perhaps for something else (or less-is-more).

The on-click display shows all the requirements necessary.

Related suggestion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250052/168244

Answer (score 2):

In the IMPACT box on my [Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/202205/pacoverflow?tab=activity), it says that I have "2 posts edited".  But when you go to my [activities/revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/202205/pacoverflow?tab=activity&sort=revisions), you will see that I have 5 total edits.

OK, so the 3 earliest edits are to my own posts, and I realize that the system is excluding edits to my own posts.  But my other 2 edits are to the same post, so it's not accurate to say "2 posts edited".  It should say "1 post edited" or "2 edits" or "2 total edits".

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - there is no pointer indicator here, so there is nothing to suggest it is clickable. This doesn't seem to be a problem for most people.

### Urge to click

Empty white box made me click it, as if doing so will switch it to green.

[image: urge to click]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I'm not sure if this relates to the new layout but bugs me now I can see it...

Other than the whitespace being odd, generally around the text and image, the 'Network Profile' baseline is 1px lower than the username baseline.

Comment: Current version of chrome on Win8.1

Answer (score 1):

**On click reputation graph reloads full page**

I noticed that reputation graph can be clicked. So I did, page reloaded and something happened. After a few clicks I noticed that it is actually switching to reputation tab on lower pane.

It should not reload a full new page. As full page reloads user can not notice what is actually changed on the page. Only the reputation tab in lower pane should be reloaded and highlighted.

Comment: And your point is... ?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It should not reload a full new page. As full page reloads user can not notice what is actually changed on the page. Only the lower pane tab should be reloaded.

Comment: This still doesn't make much sense. Every tab click reloads the page with the selected tab displayed, why make the graph different?

Comment: @ShadowWizard When one clicks on tab, he knows what he is doing. I had no idea that graph is clickable and when I found that, it took me sometime to figure out what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Badge elements and alignment is marginally off on mobile:

[image]

As specific reference, in the above:

1. Gold, Silver and Bronze badges could/should fill to the width of the other boxed content;
2. Little badge circles don't line up with the numbers the way they do with the Informed badge.
3. The Illuminator badge height is different from that of Informed.

Answer (score 1):

Low privilege requirements seem fine on mobile:

[image]

However, anything requiring 10,000+ rep is misaligned:

[image]

Also don't know why the badge dot is suddenly showing.

Comment: My suggestion here might be to use the traditional K-rouding from 1K upward. That seems the only feasibly thing under the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - this graph is not meant to be a fully featured reputation history graph.

Maybe you would consider showing the mini-tiny-cute graph since the moment when I created my account there, or make it scrollable? I am sure that I started from 101 rep, not from 2.7k.

[image]

Comment: We have the full graph for this, no need to make the tiny graph complicated.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, it seems there is no full-sized version of the above graph. Clicking the mini-graph brings up something rather different.

Comment: @Fam It is in the network profile. But what if I just want a quick overview and don't want to search for this graph in the network profile? If this graph is going to exist, it is better to make it more informative in the way I pointed.

Comment: @Fam indeed, it opens the reputation tab which is expected. I like it the way it is, small and minimalistic, what I do miss is link from the profile page right to the network profile reputation graph. This would make a fine feature request, e.g. link in the per-site profile reputation graph.

Answer (score -1):

> [image: Flair text]

Any reason that text is in a big box? And what's with all the empty space?

Comment: Why not? I like it like this. :)

Comment: We mostly didn't change these pages (other than making them work with the left nav).  There are a lot of tweaks that we can make to make em more intuitive, but we decided to push that to after we ship the new stuff.

Answer (score -3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - these are links that the user put in themselves as part of their "About Me". And we will not default these **or any other** links to open in a new tab. Because we like to keep our users in control of their browsers. That's why middle/wheel clicks exist.

Following all 3 links should open in new tab instead of same tab :

> [ Twitter ] - [ Steam ] - [ Amazon Wishlist ]

It would be more cool and suitable if above links open in new tab when user click. So user can be on profile after click also.

Comment: We have steam and amazon wishlist links? Where?

Comment: Its in "Profile page". in section "animuson"

Comment: You have an "animuson" section in your profile page?

Comment: NO , I am talking about this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson

Comment: I see. Helps if you give full details. And no, we are not doing this. Taking control of default browser actions? Nope.

Comment: okay..thanks for clarification.

Answer (score -3):

This UI is a min-maxer's paradise. Which may or may not be what you want.

Of course, I went straight to try to earn the next badge, "Critic", by randomly downvoting the question, and when that didn't get me a badge, downvoting the first answer to it. Well, shucks, I still don't have the badge, and it won't let me downvote comments. So is it broken, or what? **Where's my shiny badge?**

I'm decently sure that **inspiring people to game the system** like this isn't the point, but it's what this interface does. That's probably a bad thing.

And I didn't get my badge even after following the instructions, so that seems broken, or you need to explain in the UI that there may be a delay in getting the badge, or whatever. At the moment, it feels wonky and nonfunctional if I do what it tells me, but get no confirmation or payoff.

[Edit: badge has arrived, but it's not letting me undo my downvotes. That wasn't explained, it just told me I had to do it to get a badge. Yeah, new UI seems bad for encouraging system-gaming without also showing the more complex issues.]

[Edit2: this response was because testing something involves finding the ways in which it might break or be exploited. Whether I'm wearing the hat of programmer, security consultant, QA tech or usability tester, the first thing to ask is "what are the failure modes?" - the two points above leaped out at me, as UX issues. I'm interpreting downvotes as "other people performing the same test" rather than "people annoyed that I tested the ways in which this new UI might break" - however, it'd be good to post a comment or answer indicating whether your experience was similar and how it compared: more data points always better.]

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if you have noticed but there is a ridiculous amount of white space that totally wastes my monitor size.

Comment: Anything **specific**? As it stands, this is not actionable nor constructive.

Comment: @Oded I wish it was specific, but excessive white space is pretty much everywhere. Comparing white spaces / margin sizes between the old and the new UI would be a good place to start.