# Featured post on MSE no longer appears in the community bulletins of any SE sites

Tags: bug, community-bulletin, featured-tag

Recently I stopped seeing [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features), which is currently featured, in the community bulletins of *any* Stack Exchange communities. But nothing happened with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag on this post last time (since feb 23, when it was added), so I can't blame caching. So it appears to be a bug.

---

It happens again. And again, nowhere I can see it in the community bulletin.

Comment: Wait, it started to work just now. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Don't be too quick to dismiss the possibility of caching, for you are crunchy and taste good with cacheup.

Comment: @Tim it happened not on a single device for me... And also, how can it be caching if it worked for four days, then it didn't work for an hour and then worked again?

Comment: Server caching, not related to any of your devices. Personally I suspect that it's sometimes getting cleared, then taking some time to fill in again - @Tim can you check such thing somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system is pulling all [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions posted in the past 14 days from Meta Stack Exchange, sorting them by date, and displaying the newest two in the bulletin.

That means any featured question more than 14 days old *will not be displayed*, regardless of when the tag was added.

Given that the behavior of the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag on *every other meta site* is based around the date on which the tag was added (regardless of the age of the question itself), this does seem like a bug to me. I would prefer the behavior present elsewhere, where questions are made to drop off the list by silently removing the featured tag *n* days after it was added instead of via a hard-coded date range.

Comment: Wait, is it... It is new, isn't it?

Comment: As I know, [featured] is removed automatically by Community in a month. What's the point to keep it in a question for 16 days, after it looses its weight? Or was it changes too?

Comment: And wait, seems that you encountered a bug. Why not fix it right now? :)

Comment: And also: what's really the point in removing a question from CB when its age reaches 14 days?

Comment: @nic Shog is a CM, not a dev, so he can't fix the bug with a wave of his hands. Probably the bug got a high priority now, but might still take some time to fix.