# Adding more info (up- downvotes) to activity feed

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page, activity

As Oded clarified, I should have posted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/250499#250499) as a new feature request, so here goes.

Currently, the activity feed in one's profile looks like this. (`{user-profile}?tab=activities&sort=all`)

[image: Current activity feed]

However, in this view it is not clear how much appreciated your activity actually is. If you want to know such information, you'll have to go to the different actions in the menu above (answer, questions and so on). A summary of all your activities in a list overview *and* how they are received is not available. Therefore I'd like to suggest to add the amount of votes your actions have into the page shown above.

I understand if the upvotes for answers and questions seem redundant because these are already visible on the "answers" and "questions" page in the upper menu, however especially comments deserve the appreciation they get on posts. Currently it is not possible to get an overview of how well your comments are received, even though in my opinion they can often be as important as some answers. (Especially those comments that give additional information on an already accepted answer.)

Comments seem to be under-appreciated on SE, and maybe this addendum - a long with a mention on the "summary" tab and more badges on comments - changes that.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are [second-class citizens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/158100) as you already observed so if this feature request gets any priority is to be seen but don't expect it within [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514?s=2%7C0.9993#19514).

You can however obtain that information by using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/282610?UserId=1150863) until this gets implemented:

```
-- userid: Your user id! "found in the url of your profile page"
select score, [id] as [Comment Link]
     , postid as [Post Link]
from comments
where userid = ##userid:int##
order by score desc
```

Remember that SEDE is only update once a week, in the weekend.