# Profile "About You" placeholder text is... just weird

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

This bug is still an issue if you edit your profile in meta.stackexchange.com.

Placeholder text on "About You" textarea is:

> Tell us more about you and your the software that powers the Stack Exchange network background

This is not grammatically the profile page looks great
correct

I'm raising this bug as a new question (rather than a post within that page) as requested by @Jaydles in his post [Help us test the shiny new “User Activity” page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features), to raise a new question if a bug has been found as it is not feedback about the new features.

Comment: I supected a strange template replace action but it actually comes in this form in the http response... nice catch...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250111 - it was already reported in the thread about profile page redesign.

Comment: I was hoping that most users had filled in their profiles properly and I'd managed to catch a bug that had been there for a long time! Ah well!

Comment: @Jens: no, there is a note on that page: *Note: If you can, please post any suggestions or feedback on the changes to the "Edit/Settings" or the "Profile" page (the one others see) as a new post here on MSE.* This report falls in that category.

Comment: To whomever voted this as *can no longer be reproduced.*: The problem is **still there**. This is a problem with the new profile editor *here on Meta.SE*.

Comment: Have edited the question to explain why it isn't a duplicate and to point out that the bug still exists, without an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have already changed the phrasing on this place holder.

It now says:

> Tell us what you work on, what you enjoy, or share a favorite picture or quote