# Terse error on subsequent click on completion email link

Tags: feature-request, sign-up

I created a new account to see the text mentioned in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250605/147650). I glanced at the other preferences and, seeing nothing more to report, I followed and accepted the delete option.

I then clicked on the [Click here to complete your registration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup-finish?email=justtesting%40mailinator.com&name=Just+testing&token=8429cb21-c098-4899-8a3e-cf73d211d97f%3aRgek5swhx2bfkAliBjTa2eNiOFE%3d&authCode=3dc2e65a62f9a51848952eef1fadd7c8a03de5ed05e6f5bd8a1e52a5f2af5181) in the email again.

> That email address is already in use

IMHO there's no reason for this to be just a plaintext response.

Comment: You don't need to create a new account. Just navigate to the About Me section when editing, cut the text you already have and observe the placeholder.