# Could do with a space between the spam red box and text which follows in a user's flags list

Tags: bug, status-completed, spam

There is a space between the word as and the beginning of the red spam box, there should be a similar space between the end of the box and the word that follows.

This is what it looks like at the moment.

[image: spam and helpful]

This issue exists on both Stack Overflow and here on Meta StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, [I already reported it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250613).

Comment: It has nothing to do with the New Activity Page though as you can see this on Stack Overflow and the New Activity Page has not rolled out there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate as the User Activity page has not rolled out on Stack Overflow and yet this issue exists there.

Comment: @nicael: different bug altogether, and already reported on Meta.StackOverflow (where site-specific style issue should be reported).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [The re-design has borked the user flag history page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283617)

Comment: That thread I pointed is just collecting bugs and reqs for the new activity page and small redesigns on other sites. E.g. I posted [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250450), however this new design bug also pertained to other sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting - this is fixed and will be with you in the next build (rev. 2015.3.6.2366, meta rev. 2015.3.6.3154).