# Buttons have bad text color on hover

Tags: bug, design

Those buttons which have `button` class.

Example of such button can be find in your [profile editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current).

In usual state:

[image]

In hovered state:

[image]

Might want to use the same white text color on hover?

Comment: I vote green foreground red background on hover, maybe with an animated strobe effect.

Comment: Looks like this is **the only button** which shows the problem.

Comment: @Oded is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260080/260841) related? Looks like the same problem...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ The bug with the button I mentioned seems to be fixed due to the change in the profile layout. Maybe close mine as dupe of the newer one?

Comment: Yeah that's what I though should happen, but I though I should ask Oded whether it definitely is related (99% is, but there's always that 1%...)

Answer (score 2):

As [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250021) was completed (despite the fact the tag said deferred, I edited), the button, which was there earlier:

> [image]
>
> <sup>(sorry for the inappropriate freehand, that freehand was relevant to the linked request and I've lost the originals)</sup>

was removed. That's how this thing looks now:

> [image]

Though, it's relevant to another buttons, [which were reported recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260080/take-the-2-minutes-tour-inappropriate-color-change-upon-hovering)
.