# Broken profile picture hosted on imgur.com using file:// instead of http://

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture

My profile picture is broken on all SE sites but meta.stackexchange. I first noticed this on [my stackoverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1928529/dennisschagt). The `src` attribute of the image is  `"file://i.stack.imgur.com/JAQzE.jpg%3Fs=128&amp;g=1?s=128&amp;g=1"`. If I change `file://` into `http://` my profile picture loads fine.

I've had a problem with my profile picture before. At that time I got an error (`Invalid image type`) when changing any of my profile settings. So [my own post here at meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250160/241622) and [this post on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286854/1928529) could be relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had a profile image bug about a week ago that caused this.

I thought we cleaned up all bad profiles, but it looks like somehow yours got missed.

Should be fine now.