# Only pagination buttons appear when going to non-existent page number

Tags: bug, pagination

When I was checking out this [question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?page=31&tab=votes#tab-top), I noticed it's showing only the pagination buttons, with nothing in between:

> [image]

A little weird to me. Unless this is a prank, it's a bug of some sorts. How do I know? The OP of the question I posted posted this photo:

> [image]

With only one row of buttons. Why is there a duplicate row of the same buttons?

Also reproduced here on MSE for everyone, when directly browsing to [high page number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features?page=100):

> [image]

Expected behaviour: go to the latest possible page.

Comment: Does the bug still show up in incognito? If not, it's probably an extension.

Comment: The bug does show up

Comment: oops, not a dupe. Sorry about that - the bug here is more in design actually, since it's quite ugly to see the "naked" pagination.

Comment: No, No, No! I don't have enough rep to see that answer. Please reconsider your close vote!

Comment: No close vote, do you still see a banner? If so, it's a bug.

Comment: What banner? I don't understand

Comment: @Sha He doesn't. At least if everything's okay with his browser :) (tested with voting to close my q and then retracting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see, you went to the page where there are only *deleted* answers or no answers. Each *normal* page with answers has a pager at the top and in the bottom, and between these pagers answers are located.

But you can't expect it to work properly when you go to the empty page (which can be done only via link, the pager itself never has links empty pages).