# Profile tab hyperlink should match name change

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, recent-activity, 404-not-found

The recent user profile tab name change - from "activities" to "all actions" - was not accompanied by a hyperlink update from `...?tab=activities...` to `...?tab=allactions...`

[image]

Click on the "posts edited" link to see the 404-error.

Comment: Yeah... Looks like [a fair number of links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%3Ftab%3Dactivity%22) were broken by this change. We'll figure it out.

Comment: The name "all actions" is slightly overselling the tab, as it does not include setting bounties, voting, or marking questions as favorites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this was an oversight (as was the other link breakage that Shog9 commented about).

The "all activities" tab is back to using "tab=activity" on the URL, so those links will work the same way they always did, and I've updated the link on the impact box to go there.

Comment: Should the "xxx posts edited"-Link not also contain the Tag edits. My link shows "63 posts edited", but when I click the link I´m presented with "156 revisions". So there is a small discrepancy.

Comment: @Jehof - you can have multiple revisions on a post.

Comment: Links to [?tab=activities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%3Ftab%3Dactivities%22) are still broken.

Comment: @Keen - yes, that's to be expected. There are not all that many links to `?tab=activities` (not as many as to `?tab=activity`.