# "Congratulations" after winning a badge just looks wrong

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

[image: Says a old saying (?) that "a single image, is worth thousand words", lets just test it.]

Umm... didn't remember that I could inspect the element on this browser, so I have no idea what's wrong, so ask [Carpetsmoker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/166789/carpetsmoker), [he apparently knows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/251335#251335).

> [image]
>
> Well, thank you :-) But congratulations for what? My birthday? Drinking a beer? Finally getting around to doing the dishes?
>
> It seems the text is somehow 'behind' the grey box...
>
> Going to the web inspector and removing a few characters seems to fix it:
>
> [image]
>
> This is Firefox 36.0.1 on Linux, but also observed in WebKit.

Firefox here too.

Comment: @shadow "This is Firefox 36.0.1 on Linux, **but also observed in WebKit.**"

Comment: WebKit is not a specific browser - if you mean it's also observed in Chrome/Safari stable version then you're right but if you mean some fancy browser based on WebKit then it's not supported by Stack Exchange anyway. (there are hundreds of such browsers out there)