# What's With The Giant Overlap

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, mobile-web

I am on my browser for Samsung Galaxy 2 (phone) and while viewing my profile/activity on Meta.SE, I saw this overlap with so many different features:
[image]

It is a little too confusing to look at here. This seems to  be a bug because this keeps on happening. Probably after some weird update but I have no clue here. What is with the giant overlap with some of the new features?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250114/ and see comments there as well. (e

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is fixed, it will be live after our next production build.

Comment: Thank you! I will look out for that!