# Where Is That Bronze Badge Icon?

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, mobile-web

Again, I am using the Samsung Galaxy 2 (phone) to view my profile. After some random clicking, my screen cleared out to its normal self. Now what I am seeing is a missing bronze badge icon (in red):
[image]

It's probably [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). No! It appears in my regular profile on the computer:
[image]

So my question is... where is that bronze badge icon?

Comment: Why not post this with all other feedback in [Help us test the shiny new “User Activity” page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/168244)?

Comment: No repro.... SGS5

Comment: What browser are you using on your phone (and what version)?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Google.