# Bad grammar here

Tags: bug, badges, grammar

[image: pic]
The word ***earn*** used with the word ***edited*** is bad grammar.
It should be "Edit first post that was inactive for 6 months".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250351, didn't you know that I reported all the possible bugs? ;)

Comment: And I don't get the downvotes there - that's really a bug.