# Why am I getting different versions of my profile page on different sites?

Tags: support, profile-page, meta

My profile pages on different sites are different.

Science Fiction and Fantasy profile:

> [image: Science Fiction and Fantasy at Stack Exchange profile of Sachin Shekhar]

Meta Stack Exchange profile:

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange profile of Sachin Shekhar]

Meta Stack Exchange profile looks like a newer version. Does that mean that the SFF.SE site is under upgrade? Or, is this a user-based upgrade?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new profile page is being previewed on Meta Stack Exchange, before being rolled out to the rest of the network.

The rollout will not be to all sites initially. Only sites that have been converted to a new .less structure will get the new profile page, which, over time will be all of them. Currently that are ~25 sites (these are graduated sites - the beta theme has been converted already) who have not had their .less conversion finished.

See the following post for details:

[Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) (posted Fabruary 23rd 2015)

Comment: SO and SU are already updated. When will SciFi.SE be upgraded?

Comment: As soon as the designers finish updating the base css and styling for it. It is [in the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed) of sites waiting for that.