# How does the next badge generate?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

I am confused about the next badge. Here is mine

> [image: "Select your next badge"]

We can see the rule of next badge [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/249965#249965) . It said that "Progress to next badge" bar automatically selects the badge you're closest to earning (or that's most logical to go for next). Now my next badge is "Critic" and maybe it is most logical to go for next. Why not "Benefactor", "Citizen Patrol" or "Cleanup"? They seems to be most logical to go for next too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but if you had any of those you mentioned selected, would you ask why not "Critic" or others? I guess as these badges have the same progress to go (every requires just one action), a random of them is picked.

But of course I can say while Critic requires only one click, assuming you are browsing some question already, the others require two clicks or more.

1. Benefactor: "start a bounty" > select amount > click "next" > choose reason > type in advertisement, optionally > "Start Bounty" > wait > award. **7-8 steps**. See it? Quite complicated :D
2. Citizen patrol: "flag" > select the reason > type in some bloat, if selected "other" > "Flag Question/ Answer". **3-4 steps**.
3. Cleanup: go to the revisions > roll back. **2 steps**.
4. Critic: downvote! **1 step**.

That could probably be the reason :)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it is picked randomly.