# Impact Tooltip Cut Off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, tooltips

I did a quick search and was surprised that I didn't find it already reported. (Though [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250715/217633) also involved tooltips in that area).

Using **Firefox 39.0**, I tried to see [what Impact meant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here), and the top of the tooltip was cut off, as shown in the image below. I was also able to reproduce the issue in **Internet Explorer 11.0**.

This only seems to happen with the fancy dark tooltip that appears when viewing my own profile (as opposed to the default tooltip that appears when viewing other profiles).

[image: Impact Tooltip Cut Off]

As @NormalHuman pointed out, this also [happens on WebApps](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3808). That bug mentions the following browsers:

- Safari (Mac OS)
- Google Chrome (Windows 8.1)

Comment: Also on WebApps: [Tooltip flows under header](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3808).

Answer (score 3):

The tooltip for the Impact widget is displaying under the bottom of the **people reached** label. So it is not overlap with the header.

It has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Screenshot from Web Applications and User Experience:

[image: WebApps Impact widget] [image: UserExperience Impact widget]