# Editing existing answer vs. adding a new answer

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

Once you add an answer to a question, there is always the option to add another answer. What would be the purpose of adding a *new* second answer versus just editing your original answer?

Comment: Agree it is rare, but sometimes there can be two different answers, and even more, on same question. For example feedback requests here on MSE when a new feature is published, and the team wants users to test it. In those cases, editing the same answer makes no sense. (e.g. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features).)