# Can't see progress to badge

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

I wanted to find my progress to the [Unsung hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) badge from my profile, but it's not listed under the available badges.

I ran [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i) to get my progress, but I'm curious why isn't it showing up otherwise on any of the sites.

Comment: By design, I believe. It's not one of the badges that you can track.

Comment: Duplicate of [this report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250197/245360) on the original annoucement

Comment: thanks @PatrickHofman, it make sense now that some badges aren't listed (not worthy, resource intensive), but it's not really obvious from the UI