# How is the "Next badge" determined?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

In the tab "Activity" of my profile, there is a place for user badge settings. It is shown in the figure below:

> [image]

A user can choose his or her next badge choice from the new badge settings; otherwise, the site will suggest a badge itself. Are there any strategies for these badge recommendations? Is it random or either fixed for all users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says in [Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features):

> "Progress to next badge" bar automatically selects the badge you're closest to earning (or that's most logical to go for next), and tracks your progress toward earning it.

So the system selects the badge you're most close to earn anyway.