# Duplicate post notice sometimes overflows box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, closed-questions, responsive-design

On my (admittedly tiny) phone screen, this is what I see for some gold badge closed questions:

[image: english se example]

[When part of an object becomes the name for the whole](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/333456/191178)

---

[image: so example]

https://stackoverflow.com/q/61312680/6083675

---

MSE examples:

[Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466/323179)

[Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/323179)

---

It looks like there’s a nbsp between the username and the tag, which causes the line to overflow to the right. The main annoyance is that it causes the screen to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Let's use an [example from M.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346711/282094), while I completely disagree [browserspy.dk says my screen is 360 wide](https://browserspy.dk/screen.php). Here is a screenshot with Firefox Android, in Mobile View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OMAM.jpg --- While his name is longer in the first instance with a shorter GT ***and*** shorter in the second instance you'll note that I've got *tons* of room to the right of the tag.

Comment: @Rob Well it doesn’t happen all the time, so your link doesn’t show the bug to me either. But I did add some MSE links where I see the bug; if the first isn’t broken, the second will be.

Comment: Dev &, Laurel thanks for adding additional examples. The [first new link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466/282094) gives new meaning to "off by a decimal point"; as it's *barely* wrong, and not too bad - but still a bug. This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX4Am.png --- The [second new example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/282094) demonstrates where the problem lies, and a workaround: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3RsE.jpg --- Bug confirmed. --- It was examples on a site where I had enough rep to see the same as you that made the difference. Note new bug, right image?

Comment: To me this only happens on the second MSE link in the OP, not on the link @Rob provided. Chrome on android.

Comment: Thanks for raising. This is on our list to fix.

Comment: @JonChan any idea untill when this is deferred?

Comment: @Luuklag Just fixed; see answer.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please don't forget to upvote and [accept it by clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just deployed a fix for this.

What happened was there was a "nowrap" class for all user name links, in the screenshot above it's "Jared Smith" and "Certain Performance" in "Closed 55 min ago by Jared Smith, Certain Performance". This caused the user name links not wrapping when screen size was small and therefore overflowed outside the textbox.

The fix is adding an additional parameter in the function that renders user name links that decides if we want to use "nowrap" or not. In this particular place, we pass it as false. This class no longer applies to the user name link here, and the paragraph wraps normally now.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Can the tag please be changed to [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog done!