# Add Mastodon to the "Know someone who can answer?" social media links

Tags: feature-request, questions, sharing, social-networking

Over on https://askubuntu.com/ we have this banner under questions.

[image: A sample from Askubuntu.com - a Stack Exchange site]

Is it possible to add a link to "Share a link to this question via [Mastodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastodon_(software))"?

(Some may prefer to use [Fediverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fediverse) to refer to the various Twitter alternatives which use [ActivityPub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivityPub). I'm using Mastodon here as it's well known right now).

I've seen discussions in the past about updating, removing or blocking the *"Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook."* under each question. But not an answer on how to add support for sites.

The answer that people keep suggesting is for a different thing. The [Add a Mastodon link in addition to Twitter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383594/add-a-mastodon-link-in-addition-to-twitter) answer is for adding a social link to a Stack Exchange user's profile. That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking about the links underneath the question.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a Mastodon link in addition to Twitter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383594/add-a-mastodon-link-in-addition-to-twitter)

Comment: Nope, that's about adding it to your own SE profile, not modifying the page assets under questions.

Comment: But the answer from staff says they don't want to add it and don't think websites should bother adding them at all.

Comment: Would this even be feasible to create? Mastodon instances are (by-design) hosted across many independent domains; where would the link lead? The existing links each send the user directly to the "draft post"/ equivalent feature of the respective site, but I don't see how that would be possible for Mastodon given that there isn't a single place to send users, right?

Comment: @zcoop98 I don't know if it's technically possible. Others have tried similar things: https://www.bentasker.co.uk/posts/documentation/general/adding-a-share-on-mastodon-button-to-a-website.html

Comment: @Warcupine Again, the question you've linked to is about people's own profiles, not the section under the question (which is controlled by the site owner - stackexchange - not the user). I have clarified this by drawing a box around the section in an image in the question, to make it clearer.

Comment: If anything they should just simplify that whole thing and remove twitter, facebook, and e-mail. "Share a question using this link" is complete and doesn't become obsolete when facebook finally gives up or Elon burns twitter down or mastodon realizes it can't actually become a thing.

Comment: In other words, if you're on mastodon and you know how to use mastodon, then you know how to share a link there. Why do you need anything other than the `Share` link directly under the question? That whole line is just a waste of space.

Comment: You may read Animuson's answer as only applying to social media links in that one specific location. I, however, do not.

Comment: I would argue 2 contrary things. Firstly, that twitter has been messing up so badly that a mastodon link has more value than a twitter link. The other is that there's little value add to a direct share, when one can copy and paste.

Comment: I'd support replacing the Twitter link with something else, Twitter is not what it used to be, and SE should not encourage using it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I would say the same for facebook, and who's to say mastodon won't also end in the same place? I feel like the share link (and the browser's URL bar) are plenty, and there's really no benefit to hard-coding (and thus implicitly endorsing) _any_ specific social media links.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 so according to your logic we should just get rid of the share buttons, which is also a better option.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Yes! I said that earlier: `Why do you need anything other than the Share link directly under the question? That whole line is just a waste of space.`