# Where can I get the list of Badges by points , so that I can see what next badge I am going to get

Tags: discussion, support, badges

Where is the list of badges sorted by points earned, so that I can see what next badge I am going to get?

Is there any list like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work), [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: @TheEstablishment aka Cody - not really, he's asking too see his progress towards gaining the badges

Comment: re your edit: you still can't. No such feature exist, or can exist actually. See my answer for the badge progress options.

Comment: created a feature request for the same http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127354/woudnt-it-will-be-great-if-i-can-see-the-nearest-earnable-badge-in-my-profile-p

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports

Answer (score 10):

Badges are not given according to reputation. Badges are awarded on completion of a task specified with every badge. So you have get privileges to complete task(s) to earn the badge.

To check privileges you just have to visit the "Privileges" page from your profile, or add "/privileges" to the site URL, like so: https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges.

The link at the top of the page for [Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) will show you all the badges with their information and requirements, as well as which ones you've already received.

Comment: Allright , I got it that badges has nothing to do with points (directly), now my questions is much simpler now

Where to see what is the nearest badge I may get in future (sorted by my less efforts or if badge is depend on time then sorted by time)

Comment: Every user takes different time to earn badges. so you cant sort badges according to time. You can sort them according to class. If you want to earn with less effort, then Bronze badges are easy to achive. Just go through badget requirment and do the specified task.

Answer (score 4):

Full list of badges is available at `/badges` of every site, for example on the main site:
https://stackoverflow.com/badges

They are sorted alphabetically only, you can't change that - you can only filter them by their type: Gold, Silver, Bronze or all.

Apart of the ordinary badges, there are also "[Tag Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)" - clicking the "tags" tab in the Badges page will show you.  As you can see, those are earned by collecting enough upvotes on your answers (not questions) and you can see your "progress" in the [tags tab of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252975/imran-rizvi?tab=tags) - for example right now you need 96 more upvotes for [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) to earn the bronze badge of that tag.

Now here is something not widely known yet - you can see the progress of some badges in the `/review` page of each site. For example on the main site:
https://stackoverflow.com/review

Couldn't find any official list but got two examples of my own on two sites:

[image: badge progress main]

[image: badge progress on gaming]

That's the closest you get to what you asked for, anyway like already said - badges got nothing to do with reputation - except maybe for the tag badges that depend on amount of upvoted. In theory, one can have 100,000 reputation and gain only couple of bronze badges.

Comment: `In theory, one can have 100,000 reputation without a single badge.` Nope. There are two "first post" badges, you have to get atleast one ;)

Comment: @Manishearth dang.. forgot all about the Student and Teacher! :/

Comment: @Manishearth hmm.. still possible by getting your reputation only from bounties - posting answers, all with 0 upvotes but with bounties. However this is too extreme even in theory, lol!

Comment: Also, you can only get 36k while avoiding both Yearling and Mortarboard. SO should have a competition. Most rep with least badges(we all get to create socks) Silver badge=disqualification. Gold badge=ban ;) would be fun to do :P

Answer (score 0):

Further to the tips in the other answers, it is also possible to do this for the *Research Assistant* badge.  This progress bar is located on the 'info' tab of a tag wiki - e.g [biology.se/tags/human-biology/info](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/human-biology/info):

[image: Research Assistant Badge Progress]

---

As you would expect, once the *Strunk & White* badge has been achieved the panel on the review page switches to tracking the progress of the *Copy Editor* badge:

[image: Post Strunk & White Badge Progress]

Note that the table of reviews that appears after you have *Strunk & White* allows you to also track your progress (with a teensy bit of maths) towards the *Reviewer* badge.

---

You could also monitor your progress towards *Deputy* and *Marshal* by viewing your flagging history.  Note that only accepted Moderator Attention flags count:

[image: Flag History Summary]

---

Finally, there is a web-app that allows you to monitor your progress towards a large number of badges on any site in the SE network:

- *Legendary*
- *Generalist*
- *Nice/Good/Great Question*
- *Nice/Good/Great Answer*

This tool is available [here](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge).