# Woudn't it be great if I could see the nearest earnable badge in my profile page , inside badge section next to recent tag or last

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show How Much Statistics Left Until Badge Can Be Earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30902/show-how-much-statistics-left-until-badge-can-be-earned)

I would like to see a feature which would show me nearest badge which can be achieved in my profile page.

This maybe inside badge section next to recent tab or as a last tab.

nearest can be defined in several category e.g. Time, Points, Efforts and Overall

I hope Time and Points are understood.

For Efforts this may be a list of badges that can be earned by less efforts for example if I just have to up vote one answer to earn a badge that would be on top as up voting an answer takes very less effort.

Overall would be combination of all other categories , as it would show badge which I am going to earn in next 5 days (fixed time) and badge going to earn by single up vote. ofcourse it will show the single up vote badge first as it can be achieved very easily before 5 days badge.

Comment: Define *nearest*. For instance, if I have a question with 24 votes, 24 favourites, which is "nearer"? And what if I have visited the site for 29 consecutive days, or raised 79 helpful flags?

Comment: Wouldn't be too hard to implement, the badge scripts check this out regularly anyways. Instead of outputting a yes/no, it would make little difference to output a "75%" or whatever is relevant. Then again, I have no clue what the code's actually like :/

Comment: This already exists for the [Strunk & White](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) badge and also  [Copy Editor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/65/copy-editor).  You can see your progress towards these badges in the [Review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/) section...

Comment: I am looking for list of all the badges

Comment: I don't agree. To make it short - I believe badges should be **prize** rather than **goal**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that **too much transparency will hurt the site's quality** because transparency makes it easier to game the system. Some people game the system anyway; we don't need to make it any easier for them.  (I am *not* implying that you are among them!)

*SE karma* works by simplicity: when you **focus on good contributions,** then site rep and badges will follow. This is fundamentally a philanthropic network, so neither rep nor badges should be the focus of your attention.

The notion that other people can countervote (up/down) on votes cast by badge-chasing users is mistaken because people can't see the rationale for others' votes unless they also leave a comment. And I don't think anybody would openly comment *I just edited/voted/(?) to get closer to my XYZ badge!*

Answer (score 5):

I can see two sides to this.

On the one hand a feature that shows your progress towards different badges would be pretty neat, especially if the list was ordered with those closest to completion at the top.

On the other hand, having such a list would be a greater encouragement for people to chase those badges, than already exists, and would influence behaviour on the site. I haven't been an active member long enough to know whether that influence would be beneficial or disruptive.

Comment: I am looking it as an encouragement for me as well as other people, you can see that bounty questions has more responses the reason looks similar that they see the improvement in reputation, badge is also an improvement to reputation

Comment: I agree on your "other hand" point: making the badge mechanics too transparent would entice people to game the system rather than make sensible contributions. There would be a risk of more actions done only to achieve a badge with too little attention to the consequence (_I only need to do four more downvotes!_).

Comment: @Imran Badges and (numeric) site reputation aren't linked at all, where as bounties and site reputation have a direct link. Though if you mean the general credibility of the user on the site (e.g. "Ooh, they have a gold badge, they deserve respect!") then I see your point. :) Personally I see site reputation as the better guide for whether or not someone knows what they're talking about.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun people who answer anything to achieve a badge , others always have option to downvote them. I don't think this action would implies that much risk you are thinking.

Comment: @ImranRizvi: I'll provide a longer answer as a separate post.