# Pundit Badge - Progress checker DE link down

Tags: support, data-explorer, comment-badges

There is a link on a recently updated answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112504/197141) to a [DE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/885/new-pundit-progress), which now leads to 404 page.

Does finding the new location of this query page lead to a secret badge of infinite sparkliness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure where that link came from, but looks like it suffers from link rot.

SEDE has changed somewhat since that link was posted - I have updated the link to point to what appears to be the same query, but using a valid link.

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. I'm not sure why that saved query wouldn't have been migrated. Most historic saved query links ([example](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1924/most-viewed-posts-using-bit-ly)) should redirect to the new URLs.

Comment: @TimStone - I took a look at the query with ID 885 which appears to be something completely different. Possibly an issue with backups.

Comment: Yeah, that ID corresponds to a now-defunct object type. There's a mapping table that handles the redirections, but I guess there's no entry for the one the OP was referencing.