# Badge progress on the Badges page

Tags: discussion, badges

Would it not be preferable to have access to the badge progress on the Badges page?

At least at those where it makes sense to show their progress (like the ones shown on the review page: `#Reviews`, `#Edits` and `#Votes`). For me it would be more intuitive to find it there. There exist already several progress indicators on badges (I do not want to provide an incomplete list of them as others can do this much better): [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports)

I know that there are a badges where it makes sense and others for which it does not make sense to show their progress.

Comment: I believe the general thought is (/was) some badges are designed to be a surprise, though that might be changing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216439/help-center-states-of-a-way-to-view-progress-on-badges/216827#216827

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see your progress now through [your new Profile Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current). You can see your progress towards a badge in the `Select your next badge` dialog.

[image: dialog]

Just click the gear next to your current selected badges profile:

[image: gear]

This makes the need for this feature less in the badge dialog. While it could be there, I personally don't think it should come there since the page itself is less personal. It could be a nice addition though.