# Help center states of a way to view progress on badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

In the help center on the [What are badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges) page, the very bottom sentence links to the badges page and states:

> [View the complete list of badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) to see which ones you're close to earning.

This is on MSO, SO, Programmers (so I *presume* all Stack sites).

However, there is no way to see badge progress (unless I'm missing something).

So changing the text is required, eg

1. View the complete list of badges to see which one's you've earned
   Or
2. View the complete list of badges

If it's desired to provide a means to see badge progress, linking to [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143653/230506) would be better suited (separately to the sentence linking to the badges page).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that was just poorly-worded: while the page *does* show you badges you're close to earning, it doesn't actually *tell you which ones they are!*

Note that integrating badge progress into the badges page was in the planning stages at one point too, so it's possible that sentence might someday become accurate - but for now, I think it's less confusing to go with something like this:

> [View the complete list of badges](/help/badges) to see which ones you've earned or might be able to earn!

So, that's done.

Comment: Super! I thought the general consensus was badges were supposed to be a surprise? Also, while showing badge progress may be beneficial from pushing more activity to a system which promotes site improvements, it could have adverse effects from users gaming badges in an unsavoury manner. They could do that now, but when they know there is (eg) only 3 of 100 things left to do to gain it, people are more likely to do something unhelpful/unsavoury just to get the badge.[..Looks down at an empty can marked "worms"]

Comment: For some badges, it makes sense to show a progress: they're effectively recognition that you've put the time in to do something fairly tedious. For others, it's best avoided. I talk about this a bit more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/168293#168293

Comment: Fair point. Lance Roberts makes a good point on that where you linked to. Cheers.