# I would like to see statistics on how far away a certain badge is

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges, badge-progress

As a StackExchange user on the Badges Tab I would like to see statistics on how far away a certain badge is compared to the goal. In this way it would be easyier to see how the effort progresses.

> Edit:
>
> This question is a duplicate of the question [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports?rq=1)

Comment: It shouldn't matter. While I'm sure *you* personally contribute to the site because it's fun and a good thing to do, and not primarily to get the badge, there are thousands of users who would do *anything* to reach one. ([example.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits)) We don't want to empower them even more, IMO. (Edit: ah, it seems to exist already anyway. Ah well.)

Comment: @Pëkka: why would SE's devs spend so much time gamifying things if they don't want to encourage game behavior?

Comment: @Pëkka I think most long terms users want to contribute to the community because it's fun and you learn a lot your self, while trying to help others. The badges encourage you to spend more time on the StackExchange sites since it's a concreate goal that is measerable and that drives you to spend a little extra time on any SE site. I think most people are not evil and that they love statistics so I think this feature would be really popular if it were released.

Comment: @mikeng maybe, but those few people who just play the game create massive damage while doing it.

Comment: @Wooble there's a fine line between healthy gamification, and too much of it. There's no one who knows that better than the SE devs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you were right about my Question being a duplicate, but your proposed dupliacte was abour tag badges. I found another one now that was exactly what I was looking for. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports?rq=1