# "Related" questions breaks layout when votes >999 (when is 4 chars)

Tags: bug, design, related-questions

On the "Related" questions sidebar, when the question vote count is greater than 3 chars it breaks the layout.

The vote count clashes with the question subject text.
Also, the grey vote count background seems to stop at the 3rd char.

Grey vote count background seems to break due to:
`#sidebar .answer-votes { width: 20px; }`

I changed the votes on the problematic question to 1111 (Firebug) as this seems to be the smallest spaced chars possible for a number > 1000, and it still breaks.

Did someone code this in the early days not expecting >999 votes? :P
(Is understandable!)

---

(Right click and "view image" for larger view)

[image: vote-count-over-999-breaks-styling]

---

Link to the page I saw this on:
[Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports)
I'm guessing (hoping) the problematic related question will stay "related" long enough for users to see it.

Comment: @AnnaLear - My bad, I did do extensive searching. Sorry :(

Comment: No worries. I've lost and found that post so many times by now. :)