# Upcoming badges/privileges feature request

Tags: feature-request, badges, privileges

When one opens badges tab, one can see:

1. Earned
2. Unearned
3. All

Most often All badges is too exhaustive and usually users dont read through everything.

Most often what users are interested in is what badge am I slotted to get.

Is it possible to display something called 'upcoming badges or privileges' like for example, a user with 10 rep would have upcoming badge/privelege at 15 (upvote) and user at 45 rep would have upcoming badge at 50 (discussing). Also the user with 900 edits would have an upcoming badge at 1001st edit (just an example). Most badges are just simple numeric calculations like rep > 30, number of edits > 100, etc. So it is definitely possible to display this without using any machine-learning algorithms.

How useful would it really be? That's up for discussion.

Comment: I take the downvote as a 'not useful feature'? or 'bad question'? or both? anyways commenting here would be more useful than just downvoting :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think anyone else except of you is interested in your upcoming badged or priveleges, at least not me.

But anyway, anyone can view your upcoming priveleges by going to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/user/225797.

For you this link is shorter - https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges. You can find it in your user profile:

> [image]

Also it is possible to view progress toward some badges, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports).

Comment: I don't know about how many people find it interesting, but I think atleast some people would! It doesn't hurt to add new features. Its good to hear that its already there though. Thanks!

Comment: just accepting this as answer because it has both badges and priveleges in consideration :)

Comment: The `c` and `l` almost seem to be one letter in your image.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges <sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup>.

You'll see a list of available privileges in descending reputation requirement order, with those you've attained checked. The next privilege you're working toward should be pretty obvious.

As for badges, see: [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3230/262755)

---

<sup>1</sup> Replace `stackoverflow.com` with the domain for whichever other Stack Exchange site you want to see.
<sup>2</sup> This is the destination of the "Privileges" tab on your profile page.

Comment: That is good to know (not obvious though, I wouldn't want to type in a URL everytime nor go to help center to see MY upcoming priveleges). Thanks!

Comment: Then just go to your profile and click the "Privileges" tab.

Comment: thanks Fish Below the Ice :)