# How come the Beta badge is still being awarded on SO?

Tags: support, badges, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the beta badges stop being awarded to users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-the-beta-badges-stop-being-awarded-to-users)

Every now and then I see a Beta badge awarded on the side bar on SO.

Are old instances being rotated there when there are no other badges to show? is it a bug? is it for people coming back after 11 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here

[Should the beta badges stop being awarded to users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-the-beta-badges-stop-being-awarded-to-users/19#19)