# Why do the following redirects happen?

Tags: support, redirection

Reading another question, I noticed that some redirects take place for some URLs, such as:

- From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3 to [Should meta.stackoverflow.com replace uservoice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com/3#3)
- From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5 to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sync-meta-user-accounts-daily-with-other-family-sites/5#5
- From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7 to [Should meta.stackoverflow.com replace uservoice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com/7#7)
- From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12 to [Should meta.stackoverflow.com replace uservoice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com/12#12)
- From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14 to [Should the beta badges stop being awarded to users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-the-beta-badges-stop-being-awarded-to-users/14#14)

Except the last one, the other redirects are to questions that are deleted.

In which cases do a URL like `http://stackexchange-site.com/questions/<question ID>` redirects to an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever the ID matches an answer instead of a question. All questions and answers on the site **share ID numbers** and are stored as **posts** which are indiscriminate. The questions and answers all share the same number line.

So the "first" question 1 is started, which received answers 2, 3, and 4, which would make the "second" question have an ID of 5.

Comment: I believe tag wikis and their excerpts also share on the same number line, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Note that even though they follow `questions` in the URL, the numbers are post IDs, shared between questions and answers (and a few other types of post).

Normally the redirection happens when the post represents a question (redirects to the question, and tries to jump to the answer with the requested ID using a fragment identifier). But apparently this redirect happens even when the parent question is deleted.